# Changing feature class and field aliases in bulk using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, alias

I have over a hundred FCs, each with 10 or 20 attributes to add or change the aliases for, two or more times a year. Needless to say, this is not something I'm going to grunt my way through. How can I automate this process?

Python solution preferred but will use anything that works.

I have access to Arcgis 9.3.1 and 10 (ArcInfo license level).

Comment: I found the [Edit Feature Class Schema][1] v9.3 developer sample for ArcCatalog . It changes the alias for the selected feature classes into the value hard coded in the script. So not a batch process but headed in that direction.

  [1]: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/com/samples/developer_scenarios/ArcGIS_Desktop/Illustrated_Code_Samples/62437299-6d95-4235-9eab-0f57de51fafa.htm

Comment: related (a foundation building block): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 10.1 [AlterAliasName()](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/alteraliasname.htm)  can be used to re-alias tables:

```
table = r"C:\path\to\connection.sde\OWNER.TABLE"
arcpy.AlterAliasName(table, "table_alias")
```

As of version 10.3 [Alter Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/alter-field-properties.htm) can be used to re-alias fields:

```
table = r"C:\path\to\connection.sde\OWNER.TABLE"
arcpy.AlterField_management(table, "FIELD_NAME", new_field_alias="field_alias")
```

Answer (score 8):

With help from Mark Cederholm I have a working solution using [python and arcobjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python). It's rough around the edges, but it got the job done. After following the recipe on that page, create a new script which uses the `GetLibPath, NewObj, CType, OpenFeatureClass` functions from `snippets.py`. Also create the rename lookup tables in .csv format:

Field to Field Alias lookup (att_code-name_lookup.csv):

```
Attrib_Name,Alias_Name
CODE,Specification Code
VALDATE,Validity Date
...
```

Feature class to FC Alias lookup (fc_code-name_lookup.csv):

```
"FC_Name","AliasName"
"BS_1250009_0","Navigational Aid"
"BS_1370009_2","Residential Area"
...
```

and the script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('k:/code')
from snippets import GetLibPath, NewObj, CType, OpenFeatureClass
sWorkingDir = "k:/code/"
sFileGDB = sWorkingDir + "blank_canvec.gdb"
sResourceDir = "k:/code/"
sFCAliasFile = sResourceDir + "fc_code-name_lookup.csv"
sAttAliasFile = sResourceDir + "att_code-name_lookup.csv"
sProduct = "ArcEditor"

def BuildFieldAliasLookup():
    lookup = {}
    f = open(sAttAliasFile, "r")
    bFirst = True
    for line in f:
        # Skip first line
        if bFirst:
            bFirst = False
            continue
        sTokens = line.replace('"','').split(',')
        sFieldName = sTokens[0]
        sAlias = sTokens[1]
        lookup[sFieldName] = sAlias
    return lookup

def AlterAlias():
    # Initialize
    from comtypes.client import GetModule
    import arcgisscripting
    sLibPath = GetLibPath()
    GetModule(sLibPath + "esriGeoDatabase.olb")
    GetModule(sLibPath + "esriDataSourcesGDB.olb")
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)

    try:
        gp.setproduct(sProduct)
    except:
        gp.AddMessage(gp.GetMessages(2))

    # Build field alias lookup table
    AttrLookup = BuildFieldAliasLookup()
    # Open alias file and loop through lines
    f = open(sFCAliasFile, "r")
    bFirst = True
    for line in f:
        # Skip first line
        if bFirst:
            bFirst = False
            continue
        sTokens = line.replace('"','').split(',')
        sFCName = sTokens[0]
        sAlias = sTokens[1]
        print "Processing: ", sFCName
        # Open feature class
        try:
            pFC = OpenFeatureClass(sFCName)
        except:
            print "Could not open ", sFCName
            continue
        # Alter feature class alias
        try:
            pSE = CType(pFC, esriGeoDatabase.IClassSchemaEdit)
            pSE.AlterAliasName(sAlias)
        except:
            print "Error altering class alias"
            continue
        # Alter field aliases
        try:
            for sKey in AttrLookup.keys():
                i = pFC.FindField(sKey)
                if i == -1:
                    continue
                sAlias = AttrLookup[sKey]
                pSE.AlterFieldAliasName(sKey, sAlias)
        except:
            print "Error altering field aliases"
    print "Done."

print 'Field <--> Alias lookup table is:', BuildFieldAliasLookup()
print AlterAlias()
```

Comment: This is so close to what I need (updating field aliases).  What is the OpenFeatureClass portion of snippets look like?  Mark's code doesn't have that piece.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Jasperoid: you can comment on a specific answer by clicking the 'add comment' link, I've migrated your response on this answer.

Comment: @Jasperiod, I moved most of Mark's snippets into a module I call [parco](https://bitbucket.org/maphew/canvec/src/a76d2f784913/Canvec/Scripts/parco.py), which is where OpenFeatureClass is also. I don't remember creating it myself, but maybe I did. Anyway, there it is at [line 125](https://bitbucket.org/maphew/canvec/src/a76d2f784913/Canvec/Scripts/parco.py#cl-125).

Answer (score 6):

This code works for me in 9.3.1 ...

```
public static void TestAlterAlias(IApplication app)
{
    // make a dictionary of old/new names
    Dictionary<string, string> nameDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    nameDict.Add("qsectionalias", "qsectionalias2");
    nameDict.Add("sursysalias", "sursysalias2");
    string[] directories =  System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\Projects\EmpireOil\data",@"*.gdb",
        System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach(string dir in directories)
    {
        List<IName> fcnames = GetFCNames(dir);
        foreach (IName fcName in fcnames)
        {
            ChangeFieldAliases(fcName, nameDict);
        }
    }
}

public static void ChangeFieldAliases(IName fcName, Dictionary<string, string> aliasDict)
{
    IFeatureClass fc = (IFeatureClass)fcName.Open();
    IClassSchemaEdit3 cse = (IClassSchemaEdit3)fc;
    ((ISchemaLock)fc).ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);
    SortedList<string, string> changeList = new SortedList<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fc.Fields.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        string fldName = fc.Fields.get_Field(i).Name;
        string alias = fc.Fields.get_Field(i).AliasName;
        if (aliasDict.ContainsKey(alias))
        {
            changeList.Add(fldName, aliasDict[alias]);
            // set it blank for now, to avoid problems if two fields have same aliasname.
            cse.AlterFieldAliasName(fldName, "");
        }
    }

    // change the alias
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in changeList)
        cse.AlterFieldAliasName(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    ((ISchemaLock)fc).ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);
}

public static List<IName> GetFCNames(string wsPath)
{
    List<IName> names = new List<IName>();
    IWorkspaceFactory wsf = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactoryClass();
    IWorkspace ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(wsPath, 0);
    IEnumDatasetName enumName = ws.get_DatasetNames(esriDatasetType.esriDTAny);
    enumName.Reset();
    IDatasetName dsName = null;
    while ((dsName = enumName.Next()) != null)
    {
        if(dsName is IFeatureClassName)
            names.Add((IName)dsName);
        else if(dsName is IFeatureDatasetName)
        {
            IEnumDatasetName enumName2 = dsName.SubsetNames;
            enumName2.Reset();
            IDatasetName dsName2;
            while((dsName2=enumName2.Next())!= null)
            {
                if(dsName2 is IFeatureClassName)
                    names.Add((IName)dsName2);
            }
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```

Comment: thanks Kirk, you've no idea how long I've been trying to figure this out. I'm guessing this is C#?

Comment: Yes, C#.  Didn't test with featuredatasets though, but should work.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution [courtesy of Rob Clark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/getting-started-with-arcobjects/9027#9027):

> You could use [featureclass_to_featureclass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000020000000) with field mapping. Yes it
>   creates another feature class but you could just have an output area
>   to copy data and change aliases whilst it's doing it.

[image: FC to FC dialog with Properties open (from context menu)]

In python the syntax for the `field_map` part is tricky so go through it once interactively to set the parameters straight, let it run. Then go to [results window](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002100000013000000.htm), r-click and *Copy python snippet*. Here is a snippet re-combined into something a little easier to extend and re-use (more work could be done to break apart the pieces of the field map and properties):

```
inFC = 'e:/Canvec/fix.gdb/HD_1480009_2'
outFC = 'HD_with_aliases'
out_wspace = 'e:/canvec/fix.gdb'
where_clause = '#'      # use default
config_keyword = '#'    #    "

# build field map
fmap_out_att = 'CODE /\Specification code/\ '  # field and alias name
fmap_properties = 'true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,'  # field properties
fmap_in_att = 'e:/Canvec/fix.gdb/HD_1480009_2,CODE,-1,-1'  # input FC and field

# construct the complete field map
field_map = fmap_out_att + fmap_properties + fmap_in_att
   # results in:
   # "CODE /\Specification code/\ true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,e:/Canvec/fix.gdb/HD_1480009_2,CODE,-1,-1"


arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFC, out_wspace, outFC, 
        where_clause, field_map, config_keyword)

# the template command copied from Results window, used for building above
# arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("e:/Canvec/fix.gdb/HD_1480009_2","e:/canvec/fix.gdb","HD_with_aliases3","#","CODE /\Specification code/\ true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,e:/Canvec/fix.gdb/HD_1480009_2,CODE,-1,-1","#")
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution is for user that use SQL server as geodatabase.
you can manually change it by an SQL update command. all feature's name save in [sde].[GDB_OBJECTCLASSES] table. the alias name set simply if you change the alias column value .

```
UPDATE [sde].[sde].[GDB_OBJECTCLASSES] 
SET AliasName = 'an alias name' 
WHERE Name='your feature class name'
```

EDIT:
this method is fast method for changing the alias name . but using IClassSchemaEdit is better because in sql update method you can't use alias name until reset feature workspace.

```
Public Sub SetAliasName(FeatureClass As IFeatureClass, AliasName As String)
        Dim abjTable As ITable = FeatureClass
        Dim objClass As IObjectClass = abjTable
        Dim edit As IClassSchemaEdit = objClass
        edit.AlterAliasName(AliasName)
End Sub
```

Comment: So obvious now that I think about it! The same approach should be possible using a Personal GDB (Access .mdb) or any of the RDBMS storage options as well.

Comment: for find it in other RDBMS i think it's better to copy a backup from your RDBMS and then change the alias name by ArcCatalog then compare current database with the backup you can see the changes and find out where aliasname save.