# Updating field aliases for ArcGIS map document layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layers, fields-attributes, alias

I am on ArcGIS 10.4.1.

I have an .mxd file with a bunch of layers. The underlying database table has got new aliases for certain fields and I would like to get this reflected in the fields aliases for the corresponding layers.

- If I remove the layer and add the feature class, I have to re-set the symbology + all other layer properties such as scale ranges, labels etc.
- If I save the .lyr file first and re-apply it using `arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer`, I will get back all the symbology, but also the field aliases which I don't want.
- If I set the `symbology_only=True`, I will need to re-set all other properties manually.

I have seen the [ArcObjects code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/programmatically-alter-aliasname-for-fields-defined-in-layer-file-not-underlyin) and am able to update it using `comtypes` and C# code, however **I wonder whether there is a way to update the layer's field aliases using `arcpy`.**

I have seen that [ArcMap X-Ray add-in](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=aedc78ca0be54a3b9bf4789aadb84f1d) has functionality of updating field aliases for the map document layers, great one. However, this should be done for every map document manually, thus it's impossible to script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ArcGIS Desktop help page for [Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) it specifically says you can't update field aliases using arcpy

> Not all layer properties are accessible through the Layer object.
>   There are many properties available in the ArcMap Layer Properties
>   dialog box that are not exposed to the arcpy scripting environment
>   (for example, display properties, **field aliases**, selection symbology,
>   and so on). The UpdateLayer function allows you to replace all layer
>   properties available in the ArcMap Layer Properties dialog box using a
>   layer (.lyr) file that contains the customizations.

(emphasis added by me)

I cannot find the matching info in the ArcGIS Pro Layer page, however I also don't see any way to do it in Pro either.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I found also. However, I thought maybe someone solved it in another way, not via using the Layer object field aliases. For instance, maybe field aliases are refreshed if one would break the data source in a certain way and then fix it.