# Renaming field using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes

What I need to do:

1. rename a field name of a table/feature class
2. copy all values to the new field

So far I have done following code as @artwork21 suggests:

```
import sys
import traceback
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

## ARGUMENTS
# argv[1] = input table/feature class path
# argv[2] = input old field name
# argv[3] = input new field name  

path = sys.argv[1]
oldFieldName = sys.argv[2] 
newFieldName = sys.argv[3] 

env.overwriteOutput = True

fields = arcpy.ListFields(path)
for field in fields:
    if field.aliasName == oldFieldName:
        if not oldFieldName == newFieldName:
            fieldType = field.type
            # Add new field
            arcpy.AddField_management(path, newFieldName, fieldType)
            #Calculates the new field based on old field values
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(path, newFieldName, "!"+oldFieldName+"!", "PYTHON", "")
            # Delete the old field (if necessary)
            arcpy.DeleteField_management(path, oldFieldName)
```

How can I map `field.type` to `AddField_management` method's field type? And while the field is in a middle place, then field deleted from middle and added to the last. That does not looks like as if field name is renamed.

Is there any better solution that help me to do these things?

Comment: Your feature layer field is not being renamed here, fieldInfo.setNewName(index, "stat").  This is why you are getting your error on line row.setValue("stat", gValue).

Comment: I also assume this. but why does not it renamed the field here? I can remember that, that line of code worked for me before.

Comment: setNewName (index, new_field_name), must be for only setting new field names, not renaming existing ones.

Comment: A FieldInfo object does not do anything to the underlying data, it is simply a representation of the field properties that can be used as an input to certain tools for creating new data, similar to a FieldMappings object.

Comment: Is `old_field` a variable name or the actual name of the old field? If it's a variable name you need to use string formatting or concatenation to wrap the value of the variable with the brackets (VB parser) or exclamation points (Python parser).

Comment: old_field is the name of the variable

Comment: can someone tell me why did i get 2 negative votes here? I did not find the problem.

Comment: Did you try my suggestions?

Comment: @blah238: I also tried `arcpy.CalculateField_management(layer, new_field, "!old_field!", "PYTHON", "")`.Doesn't it what you tell me to do?

Comment: No. You are using a variable name like a string literal. Python cannot read your mind. Do as I suggested and use string formatting or concatenation.

Comment: @blah238 Thank you so much. Actually i am new in python. so at first, i did not get you.

Comment: What is the purpose of this check: `field.aliasName == oldFieldName`. A field alias name is allowed (really, intended) to be different from its name. Did you mean `field.name`?

Comment: alias name is what we are seeing when we are looking at the table.right?

Comment: An [alias](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alias#Noun) in general is a "nickname" or a [pseudonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonym). It is not necessarily equal to the actual column name in the database.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this using a combination of Add Field, Calculate Field, and Delete Field arcpy 
tools:

```
if fieldInfo.getFieldName(index) == "status":
    arcpy.AddField_management(layer, "stat", "TEXT", "", "", "50", "",        "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")                     
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(layer, "stat", "!status!", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(layer, "status")
```

Comment: I want to make the two field type same. but field.Type and AddField_management method's field_type names are not same. What to do?

Comment: @Emi, I'm not understanding what you mean by "two field type same"?  You want the value in "status", to be put in a new field called "stat"?

Comment: yes I want the value in "status", to put in the new field called "stat"

Comment: I also tried `fieldInfo.addField ("status", "stat", "VISIBLE", "NONE")` instead of `fieldInfo.setNewName(index, "stat")`. But same error happened with my code.

Comment: For rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inputFeatureClass) , maybe try rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(layer)

Comment: I tried with `layer` but it does not work. the same error :(

Comment: @artwork21 what i have seen so far is, the field is created but while i tell it to do calculate field management,it says, the field is not here.

Comment: What method are you using to create the field?

Comment: I used this method: `arcpy.AddField_management(inputFeatureClass, new_field, "TEXT")
`

Comment: The code snippet that I put in my answer using "layer" worked for me.  Use "layer" not "inputFeatureClass" for add, calculate, and delete field arcpy tools.

Comment: @Emi You seem to have tried but abandoned the method offered by @artwork21? If arcpy method is a requirement his is certainly the way that I would do it. Your attempt uses "[old_field]" which is syntax that looks odd to me.

Comment: Is there any way to map field.type at addField_management method's field type?

Answer (score 9):

You can now rename a field using core ArcGIS Desktop GP tool - [Alter Field (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000198000000). This tool provides the ability to rename fields or rename field aliases for any geodatabase table or feature class.

**This tool is available starting with 10.2.1**.

Comment: This only supports certain data formats. Notably, it throws an error on shapefiles.

Answer (score 3):

To rename a field in a table or feature class I would try the procedure described **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//019v00000007000000)**.

1. Start ArcMap and open the Catalog window.
2. Locate the database that contains the table you want to alter.
3. Right-click the table and click Properties.
4. Click the Fields tab.
5. Click on the existing text in the Field Name column and type a new name.

I just tested this on a file geodatabase table using ArcGIS for Desktop Standard 10.1 SP1 and it worked fine.

Unfortunately, after writing this I searched the What's New in ArcGIS 10.1 PDF file and found that this functionality may have been added at that version - still it could be worth testing the latest service pack of 10.0 to see if it was back ported there too.

Comment: I believe Emi is looking for a arcpy solution.

Comment: Actually I am searching for arcpy solution

Comment: My mistake - I thought @Emi said "Is there **any** better solution ..." [my bolding].

Answer (score 1):

two big problems with the code:

- if the dataType is not a FeatureLayer, the program will skip over the fieldinfo manipulations, and then try to set the value to a new/renamed field that was never created/renamed
- The two lines:

  `gValue = row.getValue("status")`

  `row.setValue("stat", gValue)`

  have a big problem. If the earlier code worked The field "status" doesn't exist.

Comment: I checked the code and while, it is a feature layer and the feature class contains a field named "status", gives the same error

Comment: If the first line works, the second line won't.

Comment: you changed the info in the layer, but are reading and writing data from/to the featureclass

Answer (score 1):

> How can I map field.type to AddField_management method's field type?

This is done automatically, according to [this post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/3718-Inconsistencies-in-Field-type-enumerations-are-stupid?p=209332&viewfull=1#post209332).

> And while the field is in a middle place, then field deleted from
>   middle and added to the last. That does not looks like as if field
>   name is renamed. Is there any better solution that help me to do these
>   things?

As I mentioned in your [other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/52626/753), your only other options are to drop and re-create the whole feature class/table or modify the column definition in the underlying DBMS.

I suppose you *could* delete all user columns and re-create them in the desired order but that's a little crazy. The script in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/1321/753) does exactly that, you could probably adapt it to your needs.

Comment: while the field.type="string", we have to pass "text" at AddField_management. I have checked it.

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me at 10.0 SP5.

Comment: It gives me error: arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of TEXT | FLOAT | DOUBLE | SHORT | LONG | DATE | BLOB | RASTER | GUID.
Failed to execute (AddField).

Comment: What version/SP are you at?

Comment: I am using 10.0. I don't know the service pack number.

Comment: Go to Help-About in ArcCatalog or ArcMap to find out. If it doesn't say what SP it is that means none (!).

Comment: there is nothing that says what SP is it

Comment: Then you have not installed any SP... try installing SP5.