# Field names change when selecting by attribute/location and then copying feature in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, fields-attributes, select-by-location

I am trying to create a tool to make my workflow faster for a routine job task.  Basically, I have a USGS 7.5 min quad layer and a feature (species) layer, and I want to ultimately create a shapefile (must be a shapefile, because I am sending these out to people who use them in a variety of GIS programs) of the species found in a certain quad and that contain the associated attribute data.  I am using ModelBuilder, and I have gotten it to go through the process of selecting the quad of interest (with Select by Attribute), use this quad selection to select the species that intersect that quad (with Select by Location), and export as a shapefile (with Copy Features).  The problem is that the resulting shapefile, while it contains all the attribute data, has lost its field names.  The field names become 'Request1', 'Request2', and so on (instead of 'Species Name', 'Common Name', etc. respectively).

I have tried using the 'Make Feature Layer' and 'Feature to Feature' tools, but without any change.  I have a Basic license, and so do not have access to the 'Alter Field Names' tool.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing or on a workaround?

Comment: The [top answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/52416) on the duplicate of "Add/Calculate/Delete field" is just as easy to implement in ModelBuilder as it is in ArcPy.

Comment: Thank-you, PolyGeo.  I was going to add that the reason the field names say 'Request_1', 'Request_2', etc. is because the shapefile I'm selecting from was joined to a table with the attributes, and the table name is 'Request.csv' (even though the column names are correct in the csv), so I guess another way to ask this question would be how can I maintain the field names from a joined csv into the result of this tool?  I will, for now though, do the add, calculate, delete, though, this is a little clunky since there are several columns to change.  Better than having the wrong names, though!