# Same field names as given in text file (in a script)

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I have a raster (ras) and a text file (T, DA, etc). When I join both then field names are like following:

```
ras.vat:T
ras.vat:DA
```

I have to access these fields using SearchCursor for further processing. 
Is there a way to avoid these long combined names and simply obtain "T" and "DA" after joining?

Comment: No, it's always been that way - back to ArcINFO. It's a way to separate the joined fields between feature classes. Theoretically you could have the same field in the join 'from' and the join 'to' feature class and they need to be both accessible hence the long join name.

Comment: Yes you can. Here is the link with explanation:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43400/how-to-join-tables-without-losing-the-original-field-names-in-arcgis
I used `arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False` in script to retain original names.

Comment: Thanks @Ibe that's a new one by me, they change things from time to time and I can't check everything so I'll be the first to admit that I'm incorrect. How then does it resolve FeatClass.Field against RelatedTable.Field if the name is the same?

Comment: The join field is same as before with `arcpy.JoinField_management` but original names as given in tables will become Field names if use `arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False`. You can control it from "Environment/Fields" if running inside ArcGIS.

Comment: I am unclear - have you answered your own question and it is a duplicate of the one you have linked to, or do you still have the problem despite setting that variable?

Comment: @ChrisW: I answered myself. It is a duplicate except I also figured how to do it in a standalone script.

Comment: I might then suggest either revising the question (title) to specify 'in a script' and adding your variable comment as an answer with a link to the other question, or adding your additional information (as answer or edit) to the other question and flagging this one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. Here is the link with explanation: [Joining tables without losing original field names in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43400/how-to-join-tables-without-losing-the-original-field-names-in-arcgis) I used 
`arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False` 
in script to retain original names.