# QGIS 2.0 Table Join creates unwanted prefix in field names

Tags: qgis-2, table

I used to join shapefiles and CSV files via the "joins" tool in the layer properties just fine in QGIS 1.8.  Now I've updated to QGIS 2.0, and when I do the exact same thing, QGIS puts the name of the CSV source as a prefix in the field name: for example instead of just naming the field "area" it's now labelled "sourcefile_area".

I Googled it, and searched in the QGIS settings, but didn't find anything that helped, maybe I just don't know what exactly to search for though.

Comment: similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78555/keep-the-same-field-headers-after-joining-a-table-to-a-shape-file-in-qgis?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS will always put a prefix. You can minimize the prefix length by renaming the layer before joining it to the target layer. You can even have an empty layer name. Then the only thing that will be prepended is "_".

Comment: Thank you very much Underdark!
I could have thought of changing the file name... I was just wondering because with QGIS 1.8 ist worked without prefixing, but now i saw what you posted in the similar question you mentioned.