# ArcMap generated "*.sr.lock" files interrupt Append function

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, append, lock

Whenever I try to append several shapefile tables in ArcMap I receive a "read-only" error associated to the recipient file. Several 'sr.lock" files are generated associated to this failure and I cannot find how to eliminate them from the archives. Already tried turning off virus scan but still having the same problem.

Any ideas?

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 and trying to append 3 assessor's parcel shapefiles (with previously merged data) to one parcel shapefile, also with previously merged data. All merged data and field formats are the same for the four files. There are approx 200,000 observations per shapefile.

The shapefile tables maintain reference to the previously merged data using long field titles on some of the fields.

Comment: ERROR 000262: target parcels..."is read only"

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS can sometime be unpredictable. sr.lock may appear for a [number of reason](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011134),

- the file associated is being accessed by ArcMap or ArcCatalog
- the file associated crashed (with/out an error message)
- missing COM components

The sr.lock files are safe to delete if the program is closed or the processing is done. Also [try these](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010290). About the field name - there is [little luck](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15784/how-to-bypass-10-character-limit-of-field-name-in-shapefiles) if they are 10+ character. Try 'field aliases' instead. Or better, use file geodatabases.

Comment: to add on to this: find the location where the shapefiles are, save and exit out all ArcMap instances. if the .srslock files persist then delete them. I have had cases where they hang until a reboot/log off