# How to have a CSV load correctly into a template geodatabase with a specific schema and field domains?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, csv, import

My goal is to be able to batch process a folder of CSV tables to a geodatabase template. My process right now is CSV -> XY Event layer -> shapefile -> append to template geodatabase. But the problem is that some attribute are not added even though the column headers are the exact same in the CSV and the geodatabase.

My question is how would I get the schema of both the CSV and the geodatabase to match exactly so the process of appending is completely seamless?

Here is an example of what I need to match:
[image]

All of the Target Fields have A Matching Source Field but it is not picked up automatically. I need it to be automatically matched while using append so that I can batch a folder of CSVs, rather than process them one by one.

Comment: Don't save the Event layer to Shapefile because it will truncate field names to 10 characters. Try appending the Geodatabase with the Event layer. If you must first save to disk before the Append, save to file geodatabase.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the event layer into a file geodatabase so that the longer field names are not truncated.  Shapefile field names can only store 10 characters by default.

Here's a bit more info:  [How to bypass 10 character limit of field name in ShapeFiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15784/how-to-bypass-10-character-limit-of-field-name-in-shapefiles)