# qgis field calculator truncates column names with more than 10 characters

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, limitations

I am currently working with the field calculator as I want to copy the values from one attribut "join_id" to the attribut "edgeid" within one layerfile. The attribut structure looks like following:
[image]
The way I realize this with the field calculator is this:
[image]

So far, so good. The values are successfully copied into the edgeid attribut now. But strangely, in the output file of this calculation, all column names which exceed the number of 10 characters, are truncated to 10 characters. Is there a possible way to increase this limitation without changing the name manually afterwards in the properties?
In the following, you can see the truncated column names of the outputfile of the calculation:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Was you outputfile a shapefile? It has a well known 10 character limit in field names. Import to GeoPackage, SpatiaLite, GML etc. keeps the long names.

Comment: related; https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15788/81214