# How do I change the default field name length setting for a feature in Earth Engine?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth-engine, arcgis-pro, features

I am trying to export a Feature Collection from Earth Engine to view in ArcGIS Pro, however I want to set and prefill certain fields in the attribute table. The issue I am encountering is that my field names are truncated when I view them in ArcGIS Pro. Is there a way to define the field name length so that my field names do not become shortened?

`function vectorise(classifiedImage1, classifiedImage2, roi) { return classifiedImage1.updateMask((classifiedImage1.select('classification').eq(1)).and(classifiedImage2.select('classification').eq(0))) .toByte() .reduceToVectors({ geometry: roi, geometryType: 'polygon', scale: 10, maxPixels: 9e9, tileScale: 16 }) .map(function(feature) { var areaHa = feature.area({'maxError': 0.001}).divide(10000).toFloat(); var fieldsDict = {AreaHa: areaHa, Ign_Year: Year_of_interest, Sensor_Source: 'Sentinel 2 Level 2A', Ignition_Season: season, last_edited_date: ee.Date(Date.now()), Ign_Month: months}; return feature.set(fieldsDict); });`

This is the part of my code I am using to create the vectors from a classified image and define the fields. For example, the 'Sensor_source' field reads 'Sensor_sou' in ArcGIS.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, what a simple solution after all that! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earth Engine does not truncate field names except when necessary. I'm guessing you are exporting in the shapefile format — [shapefiles only support 10-character field names.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15784/bypassing-10-character-limit-of-field-name-in-shapefiles) To avoid this problem, export using one of the other supported formats, such as CSV or GeoJSON.