# Creating bulk field aliases for several layers within same ArcSDE feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, alias

I have an ArcMap with ~200 layers from the same sde feature class.  After I finished adding all the layers it was brought to my attention that we need to add field alaises for the attribute table.  Does any one have a python script that will loop through all the layers in a map and add the aliases?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ArcObjects to modify aliases as they aren't exposed to the python API.
[Changing feature class and field aliases in bulk using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255/how-to-change-feature-class-and-field-aliases-in-bulk) has a 3 methods for changing the field aliases at the feature class level. One using arcobjects via dot net, one using arcobjects using python via an unsupported backdoor, and the third through geoprocessing, but this last duplicates data.

A person should be able to build something to modify map layer (.mxd) or layer file (.lyr) field aliases using those examples; it will take some software development smarts.

Comment: ok, then I will have to have one of our developers help me.  Thanks