# split polyline with point and add vertex on that point as well as reflect in attribute table?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I am new to ArcGIS.

I am using the ArcObjects SDK and I couldn't understand how to:

- Add vertex to that clicked location as well
- Add attributes in that attribute table.

Can someone suggest some books so that I can get better knowledge of ArcGIS.

Comment: Your question in it's current state is far too broad. Questions on this site generally tend to be focused and have a narrow scope. Additional, a lot of information is missing. Please indicate what version of ArcGIS you have, and what exactly you are trying to do. This post can help you in improving your question: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question

Comment: For resources on learning ArcObjects, please have a look at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/getting-started-with-arcobjects

Comment: Unless you are working with esri topology. You will have to manage the lines and the points yourself.  Regardless esri does not support in any format multiple feature types in one data layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found ArcGIS Desktop .NET SDK help the best one.
you can cast your polyline object to IPointCollection object and then add your IPoint objects to this collection.Even better interfaces like IPointCollection1,2,3 you can use.Hope this helps.

ArcGIS Developer help description for IPolyLine.SplitAtPoint is "Adds a new vertex along the curve as the specified input point, or the projection onto the curve of the specified input point" so it doesn't make two splited polyline from th first one.IFeatureEdit.Split provide your desired function and maybe IFeatureEdit2.SplitWithUpdate even the latter doesn't delete the origin polyline but adds 2 new splitted polylines along the first one.

Comment: as per your suggestion i used IPointCollection and added to exiting point and its added into point and also i used Polyline.SplitAtPoint property for spliting that polyline into two different polyline but its not working. is this possible to Use IFeatureEdit.SplitWithUpdate to do this.if you have any sample for this using above any property then send me link please.