# Learn ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects

Is it mandatory to have ArcEngine Licence to learn ArcObjects?I was able to develop Addins for arcmap but I need in-depth knowledge of ArcObject so started exploring MapControl Application but it started flashing message boxes for using Unlicensed control.If ArcEngine is must then is there any trail version of Arcengine 10.2 Licence available for learning.Is there are any online manual to learn ArcObjects.

Comment: Did you install your API from Engine? It sounds like you already have ArcGis installed. You need a license of some sort but don't need engine if you have installed and licensed ArcGis. Contact your local ESRI distributor and discuss your needs as the licenses and extensions required depend on what you're doing or intend to do with your code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to license [ArcGIS Engine](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisengine/common-questions) which gives you interface for interacting with ArcObjects components. Your option is to get **EDN license for development-test from your local Esri distributor**. This is the most common way to get started ArcGIS Desktop development. Here is the list of what you get with [EDN](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/edn/what-you-get).

To learn ArcObjects, you might like a new book published recently: [Beginning ArcGIS for Desktop Development using .NET](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118442547). Esri [Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Learning_ArcObjects/0001000000p1000000/) is very comprehensive and has multiple tutorials too.

PS. **Evaluate your needs carefully to see if you really need to use ArcObjects.** It has a slightly steep learning curve and there isn't very much new happening in this area. There is a good chance that in several years you will end up with code that will be hard to maintain and develop further. If you really need a customized Desktop application, then yes, ArcObjects is the only platform (apart from my favourite MapObjects */old days/*) applicable. Otherwise, consider developing a web based application by using ArcGIS Server REST API + Web Mapping API (JS); ArcGIS web APIs have become much more powerful over last years and you will be amazed how much of desktop application functionality can be moved into a web-based solution.

Esri is investing into Python, so you might like taking a look at Python toolboxes, Python add-ins and Python script tools. If you are comfortable with Python libraries, consider using [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) or [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) when you need a GUI and need to wrap some ArcGIS functionality (I've succeeded in wrapping arcpy functions within both of them).

Comment: @Alex_Tereshenkov thanks for sharing you view.I have very good experience in web application using ArcGIS web APIs (Javascript , silverlight) and experience from installation to configuration to final development of web application in 2 major projects but i have almost none experience in ArcObjects and all opening in this part of the world ask for ArcObjects so if I get at least small knowledge will be great.So i want to learn ArcObjects.If you could share some more knowledge from your experience will be helpful.

Comment: Apart from the resources mentioned (Esri help has all you need to get started) - some gis.se posts http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/arcobjects-resources, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/getting-started-with-arcobjects, a good PSU course: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog489/l2.html