# ArcGIS Runtime .NET resources

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, references

Are there any books/blogs/youtube channels/websites, for beginners, that provide training for ArcGIS Runtime for .NET (C#).

I know of this [Add a map to your app](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/add-a-map-to-your-app.htm) resource provided by ESRI (which seems quite good upon further inspection). But I was interested to see if anyone had found anything else?

Given the relative infancy of the ArcGIS Runtime SDKs, I don't expect a plethora of responses to this question.

Comment: You should have look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/arcobjects-resources

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've used most of those resources for learning ArcObjects. However, ArcObjects is not the same as ArcGIS Runtime for .NET, in fact one of the purposes of ArcGIS Runtime is to break away from COM-based ArcObjects.

Answer (score 1):

My book about ArcGIS Runtime was recently released on Amazon: https://amzn.com/1785885456

Comment: Self-promotion is generally frowned upon, however, as there is a lack of other answers, this appears to be the best answer.  However, could you please edit the answer to include more than just a link (links tend to go stale)?  Perhaps, the title of your book, and maybe some of your credentials as to why someone should buy your book?  However, I think this is better written in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

I've been learning Esri runtime sdk .net on my own as well and I found that learning by examples is the best way, this Esri Repo is extremely helpful resource and updates often:https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet. Hope this helps.