# Getting from IFeatureClass on annotation feature class to IAnnoClass using ArcObjects

Tags: python, arcobjects, annotation, comtypes, classextensions

I am working in Python 2.6 and ArcGIS 10.0 through comtypes, so I have full ArcObjects access.  For example, see [the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/4982/115) I tacked onto [Accessing ArcObjects from Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/accessing-arcobjects-from-python).  That makes this strictly an object model traversal question.

I have an IFeatureClass on an annotation feature class.  I need to get to IAnnoClass to get the ReferenceScale property.

How do I do that?

I am guessing that it starts with the Extension property inherited from IClass, but I may be way off base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a feature class is an annotation class, its [IFeatureClass.Extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Extension_Property/0025000000vw000000/) will be a reference to the [AnnotationFeatureClassExtension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00120000002t000000) coclass instance. It can be directly cast to [IAnnoClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IAnnoClass_Interface/0012000001qs000000/) interface.

In short, you are right, the [Extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Extension_Property/0025000000vw000000/) property will be an object which implements [IAnnoClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IAnnoClass_Interface/0012000001qs000000/).