# Drawing graphics onscreen using Draw/Refresh/PartialRefresh methods and ArcObjects

Tags: python, arcobjects, references

I find myself woefully lacking in understanding of when, why, and how (which type) to do screen draw/refresh/partial refresh.  For instance, in a standalone Python script outside the application boundary, I have a function that is trying to draw graphic elements in the data view.  Specifically, the elements will be a TextElement on top of a RectangleElement.  The function loads the two elements into a GroupElement, which is in turn added to the ActiveView's GraphicsContainer for drawing on the screen.  (As far as I can tell the graphic elements are valid.)  I am really not understanding what Draw/Refresh/ParitalRefresh methods to put where.

Can you give me or point to a good explanation or tutorial about screen drawing/refreshing?

Below is a bit of selected code from my function.  I have a PartialRefresh in the last line, but I don't know if that is correct or not.

```
pGroupElement = NewObj(esriCarto.GroupElement, esriCarto.IGroupElement3)
pTextElement = NewObj(esriCarto.TextElement, esriCarto.ITextElement)
pRectElement = NewObj(esriCarto.RectangleElement, esriCarto.IElement)
.
.
(configure TextElement)  [tedious code removed]
.
.
(configure RectElement)
.
.
ptxtElem = CType(pTextElement, esriCarto.IElement)

pGroupElement.AddElement(ptxtElem)
pGroupElement.AddElement(pRectElement)

pContainer = mxDoc.ActiveView.GraphicsContainer

pGrpElem = CType(pGroupElement, esriCarto.IElement)

pContainer.AddElement(pGrpElem, 0)

mxDoc.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriCarto.esriViewGraphics, None, None)
```

**Added:**  So, is creating objects with the following code - as I do now - not creating them in process?

```
def NewObj(MyClass, MyInterface):
    """Creates a new comtypes POINTER object where\n\
    MyClass is the class to be instantiated,\n\
    MyInterface is the interface to be assigned"""
    from comtypes.client import CreateObject
    try:
        ptr = CreateObject(MyClass, interface=MyInterface)
        return ptr
    except:
        return None
```

If not, I gather I must use IObjectFactory.  Assuming that my current objects are not in process, I must say I haven't seen any great performance hit, but I guess I'm just asking for trouble forcing lots of interprocess calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, in the light of the tips in Kirk's link ([ArcMap Automation: Man the Message Pumps!](http://www.palladiumconsulting.com/blog/sebastian/2008/02/arcmap-automation-man-message-pumps.html)) and the knowledge that IObjectFactory must be used your scenario, here's my 
take on Python implementation of the discussed workaround.

To reiterate, the problem is that RPC calls, coming from a different process (python) might get stalled in ArcMap. The general idea described in the aforementioned article is that by pummeling ArcMap's message loop with WM_NULL messages, you force it to process your RPC calls as well.

I am not versed in Python, in fact this might only be my fifth piece of Python code or so, if memory serves. If anyone wants to improve/fix it in any way, go ahead. I ran it on Python 2.6.5.

```
import ctypes
import threading

class EsriAppMessageHelper(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, windowHandle):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = True
        self.windowHandle = windowHandle

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageA(self.windowHandle, 0, 0, 0)
            #print 'WM_NULL to window %d sent' % self.windowHandle

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.stop()
```

Basically, it's a thread which sends WM_NULL (0) messages to the given window. The `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions support Python's `with` statement. Here's how it's used (the ArcObjects related functions are taken from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/python-comtypes-and-arcobjects-error-creating-approt-object/5082#5082) in a different question):

```
# Get the ArcMap's IApplication reference.
# We're in a different process than ArcMap's, so it gets resolved using IAppROT.
app = GetApp()

# WM_NULL messages will be sent from another thread while
# this block is executing
with EsriAppMessageHelper(app.hWnd):

    objectFactory = CType(app, esriFramework.IObjectFactory) # use IObjectFactory
    mxDoc = CType(app.Document, esriArcMapUI.IMxDocument)
    graphicsContainer = mxDoc.ActiveView.GraphicsContainer

    textElement = CType(objectFactory.Create("esriCarto.TextElement"), esriCarto.ITextElement)

    # initialize the symbols and elements, assign their geometries
    # etc...

    graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0)
    mxDoc.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriCarto.esriViewGraphics, None, None)

# At this point, we're out of the WITH block.
# The separate thread is stopped and no more WM_NULL messages are being sent.
print "DONE"
```

Try it out. I could not *fully* test it with my ArcMap 10 setup because I did not have any issues with the active view refresh before (it executed immediately and refresh was successful), but the WM_NULL messages do get sent.

Comment: Understood, I as well find this a rather nasty workaround..

Answer (score 7):

If you're "in a standalone Python script outside the application boundary" I think you'll need to use IObjectFactory. See page 13 of http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis/upload/misc/python_arcobjects.pdf

Also, if you're trying to refresh the display across a process boundary, you may need to send some extra windows messages to force a refresh.  Here's [a good explanation](http://www.palladiumconsulting.com/blog/sebastian/2008/02/arcmap-automation-man-message-pumps.html).

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while since I have done anything like this, but, if the elements are located on the page layout instead of within a data frame, they are handled differently. See [Working with PageLayout elements](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000038s000000) and [Working with map elements](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_map_elements/0001000001rv000000/)

Also see [How to redraw the display](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_redraw_the_display/000100000242000000/)