# Arcobjects in Python: assign interface to objects with feature (shape) geometry

Tags: arcobjects, python

I am trying to use ArcObject in Python. I do have problem with assigning an interface (i.e. IZ.InterpolateZsBetween) to my object with geometry data, code is:

```
from Comtypes.client import CreateObject, GetModule
import arcgisscripting

gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.setproduct("ArcInfo")

esriSystem = GetModule("C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/com/esriSystem.olb")
esriGeometry = GetModule("C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/com/esriGeometry.olb")
esriDataSourcesGDB = GetModule("C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/com/esriDataSourcesGDB.olb")
esriGeoDatabase = GetModule("C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/com/esriGeoDatabase.olb")

sPath ="c:/temp/test.gdb"
pWSF = CreateObject(esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory,\
                    interface=esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)
pWS = pWSF.OpenFromFile(sPath, 0)
pFWS = pWS.QueryInterface(esriGeoDatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)
pFClass = pFWS.OpenFeatureClass("test_z")
pFCursor = pFClass.Search(None, True)
pFeat = pFCursor.NextFeature()
pIZ = pFeat.QueryInferface(esriGeometry.IZ2)
```

Why this is not working?
The output is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#175>", line 1, in <module>
    pIZ = pFeat.QueryInterface(esriGeometry.IZ2)
   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 1078, in QueryInterface
 self.__com_QueryInterface(byref(iid), byref(p))
 COMError: (-2147467262, 'Taki interfejs nie jest obs\xb3ugiwany.', (None, None, None, 0, 
 None))
```

So I tried:

```
pShape = pFeat.ShapeCopy
pIZ = pShape.QueryInterface(esriGeometry.IZ2)
pShape.InterpolateZsBetween(0, 0, 0, 4)
```

And this is working. 
But how to stick it back and save it in my feature?
I am learning Python and ArcObjects, so please be understandful.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: COM and Python doesn't look very pretty, but this is the route that will get you what you want. +1 for getting this far so fast!

Comment: You can pretty it up a bit with some [helper functions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/python-comtypes-and-arcobjects-error-creating-approt-object/5082#5082).

Comment: Aparently COM and Python does not go in pair well, but I was thinking that Python would be good place to start my adventure with programming as it seems quite user friendly. Once I'll acomplish this task, I'll start to look at C# or C++. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`IZ`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000043z000000) interface is implemented only on the [`Polygon`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PolygonClass_Class/002m0000045r000000/) and [`Polyline`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PolylineClass_Class/002m0000045t000000/) classes, which you obtain from the [`Shape`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0025/002500000330000000.htm) or [`ShapeCopy`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0025/002500000331000000.htm) properties of an [`IFeature`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeature_Interface/0025000002q9000000/). You can't QI between interfaces that aren't supported (either implemented or inherited) by an object. Use the documentation for one of the [ArcObjects SDKs](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgissdks/10.0/about) to see the interfaces each class implements. [Reading the Object Model Diagrams](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000306000000) (listed under each namespace in the help, [example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/Arcobjects_net/pdf/GeoDatabaseObjectModel.pdf)) can also be very helpful to see the inheritance/implementation relationships between the various classes and interfaces.

As for your actual workflow, you'll need to use the [`Update`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002tq000000) instead of [`Search`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16533/arcobjects-in-python-assign-interface-to-objects-with-feature-shape-geometry) method on your feature class to obtain an [update cursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000002rs000000.htm), and then set the `Shape` property of the feature to the result of the [`InterpolateZsBetween`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/InterpolateZsBetween_Method/002m0000044t000000/) method and finally call [`IFeatureCursor.UpdateFeature`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/UpdateFeature_Method/0025000002w2000000/) (thanks for the correction @Ragi).

Comment: Everything is correct, except you do not want to call IFeature::Store using an UpdateCursor (it defeats the purpose of using an UpdateCursor). You want to call UpdateFeature instead. http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/UpdateFeature_Method/0025000002w2000000/