# Creating point to center of polyline?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, point, linestring

I'm trying to create a points in the middle of polylines. The data is now in the form of shapefile.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What software do you have available? If you have ArcGIS, you can use the `Feature Vertices to Points` tool to get the midpoint of a line as stated in [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/how-to-find-the-mid-point-of-a-line-in-arcpy). You can do this in 10.1 with a trial licence (Advanced).

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple way to find the center of lines  in QGis:
Vector > Analysis > Mean Coordinates

[image]

This worked very nice and fast.

Points are created in another shapefile, and the attribute table already comes with the coordinates along with the Unique ID field you selected earlier.

[image]

I tried before to convert the lines into polygons, then extracting the polygon centroids, but the new solution is one step shorter.

Comment: This does not help. I tried this on an exploded line layer that was converted from a polygon layer, but it creates centroids outside the lines instead of in the center of the exploded lines.

Answer (score 3):

if you have qgis;

1. use SPIT - Shapefile to PostGIS Import Tool to adding your shapefile as postgis table
2. run this query:

.

```
SELECT id, ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(the_geom)) as Cetroids FROM myPolyLines;
```

or

```
SELECT id,CENTER(the_geom) as Cetroids FROM myPolyLines;
```

> ST_Centroid — Returns the geometric center of a geometry.

Computes the geometric center of a geometry, or equivalently, the center of mass of the geometry as a POINT. [more info](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html)

it will return you centroid of your line then you can update or set it as new column or anything.

[image: centroid]

Answer (score 2):

use [feature vertices to point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003p000000) in arcmap : Arctoolbox => data management tools => Features => Feature Vertices to point => select mid point type .