# How do I create midpoints for a set of polylines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create midpoints for a set of polylines in QGIS. My python knowledge is poor and was wondering if there was a plugin that did if for me.

I have tried using the Mean Coordinates function suggested in [Creating point to center of polyline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41174/creating-point-to-center-of-polyline) but this returns a centroid which is sometimes off the line (especially when lines are not straight). I am essentially looking for a point that is on the line half way along.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "midpoints **for** a set of polylines"? The points of the vertices of the medial axis for example? http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Straight_skeleton_2/index.html

Comment: I have a data set of polylines, for each polyline I would like to create (in a new layer) a set of points located on the lines at exactly half their length. If I had 100m polyline the point would be located on the line at 50m from the start.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with the term **polyline**. A **polygon** is, in OGC terms, an areal data structure and its border is a circular  buffer . So it is diffucult to say what is the mid point because of is in-determined start- & end point on that **ring**. You want to split a set of  **linestring**s (OGC terms), which a spatial linear buffer with a start & end point and length, in two parts with a equal length?   (.. look at geometry primitives 2d in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

Comment: Sorry I was using MapInfo language I now assume. I am looking for the midpoints of a linestrings.

Answer (score 2):

There is a GDAL tool **Points along lines** (in `Processing Toolbox | GDAL | Vector geoprocessing`).

[image]

Start this tool, then set the `Distance from line start represented as fraction of line length` parameter to `0.5`.

[image]

This `0.5`, being the fraction, puts a point at the middle of the line. For you most important part of this tool is that the points are placed on the line(s).