# Creating point at midpoint of polyline with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geometry

I have a polyline shapefile (that contains multiple lines) and am trying to create a point at the midpoint of each line using Python. I am currently using the ET Geowizards tool 'PolylineToPoints' which does exactly what I want it to... but I am trying to avoid using ET Geowizards (as it is causing other issues).

Is there a way to do this in Python using Arc tools and functions?

Comment: When you say centroid, do you mean the midpoint of the line, or the vertices along the line?

Comment: sorry, it should be midpoint. i will change it in the question.

Comment: @Afidus I've updated my answer to reflect this change in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should do it in arcgis...

```
import arcpy, math, datetime, numpy

print ("starting")
start = datetime.datetime.now() # for calculating time of process

#setting the containers
midpoint = #put your file to be populated in here, make sure it already exists
polyline = #put your polyline file in here

#housekeeping
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(midpoint)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#generating the mid point
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyline, "SHAPE@") as in_cursor, \
arcpy.da.InsertCursor(midpoint, "SHAPE@") as out_cursor:
for row in in_cursor:
    midpoint = row[0].positionAlongLine(0.50,True).firstPoint
    out_cursor.insertRow([midpoint])

#tidy up
del rows, row, updateRows_midpoint, outRow, out_cursor, midpoint, polyline
print "Done in ",datetime.datetime.now() - start, " seconds"
```

Comment: How do you use the `arcpy` module outside ArcGIS?

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: Just saw that the question was changed to ask for the *midpoint* of a polyline, rather than a *centroid*. You can use Field Calculator to determine this location, as I explained in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31890/4669).

> The [Polyline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polyline/018z00000008000000/) class has a new method called "positionAlongLine" in ArcGIS 10.1. This will return a [PointGeometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/PointGeometry/018z00000039000000/) object with exactly one point at a specified distance from the starting end of the line, *or a fraction of the distance between the start and end*. To find the midpoint, you would just need to do `positionAlongLine(0.5,True)`. To find the midpoints for lines and add their coordinates to the attribute table, you could do Field Calculator on the following statement:
>
> - `!Shape!.positionAlongLine(0.5,True).firstPoint.X`
> - `!Shape!.positionAlongLine(0.5,True).firstPoint.Y`
>
> Note that you need to be using the Python parser in field calculator for this to work.

---

The easiest method to find the centroid of a line is to use the [Feature To Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003m000000) geoprocessing tool, where your polyline shapefile are the `in_features`, your output points are the `out_features`. However, this tool is only available with the ArcGIS Desktop Advanced license (formerly ArcInfo).

---

If you don't have access to the Feature To Point tool, you can calculate the centroid of a line "manually" in the attribute table. Here's how you would do it:

- Add two new Double fields to your polyline shapefile attribute table.
- Use the [Calculate Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s00000027000000) function to store the X and Y coordinates of the poyline centroids in the Double fields you just created.
- Export the attribute table to a new table.
- Use the [Make XY Event Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006z000000) geoprocessing tool on the two coordinate fields to create a point event layer based on the centroid coordinates.
- Export the event layer to a new file.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i do have access to arcinfo, but i am trying to avoid it if necessary. i will try the manual approach and get back to you.

Comment: If you are still running 10.0 (as I am), then you can use the python Shapely library to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

with arcinfo, there is a built in function :

```
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(input,output,"MID")
```

Comment: thanks! although i do have access to arcinfo...the script i am creating is meant to avoid any advanced licenses so that anyone can use it.