# How to use InsertCursor to add points to a point feature class?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I am struggling with a very simple task of inserting "SHAPE@XY" into a point feature class.
Following is what I have:

```
xy = [(361087.15436001675, 198747.07296730898), (361530.56426259346, 198976.62248019245),
      (361692.3015462744, 197815.78617074457), (361845.0959187896, 198297.07296730898),
      (362135.3345548634, 197552.7531621556)]

fc = "C:/temp/xy.shp"
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@XY"])
for row in xy:
    cursor.insertRow(row)

del cursor
```

it throws back error:

```
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

I used field calculator to add x and y field into the same shapefile form where I retrieved these points, and it works fine to add above set of co-ordinates to a multiline feature class, but above set of lines fail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `cursor.insertRow([row])` instead

Comment: great! it worked.

Comment: it returns with; AttributeError: 'arcpy.da.SearchCursor' object has no attribute 'insertCursor'

Answer (score 3):

I found [**this article**](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40604) on ESRI an support page.

You've got a syntax error in your definition of **`xy`**.  According to the website,

> To be properly recognized, a single value tuple should be written with
>   a trailing comma.

Try the following:

```
xy = [((361087.15436001675, 198747.07296730898),), ((361530.56426259346, 198976.62248019245),), ((361692.3015462744, 197815.78617074457),), ((361845.0959187896, 198297.07296730898),), ((362135.3345548634, 197552.7531621556),)]
```

The rest of your code should work fine.

It's kind of a pain, but it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but will give it a shot later. Above one liner provided by @Jason worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create `arcpy.Point` geometry from your coordinates and assign it to `SHAPE@`

```py
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@"])
for row in xy:
cursor.insertRow([arcpy.Point(*xy)])
```