# How to place points along a line in a specific offset using python / arcpy?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a street shapefile with information about the street name, house number from / to on the left side and house number from / to on the right side.

My aim is to create a point shapefile that visualizes all houses along the streets. A first prototype is already implemented. With a Search-cursor I am reading out the total number of houses by building the range by using the paramaters **house number from / to on the left side** and **house number from / to on the right side**. The total amount is divided by the length of the street so that I have a value that show me in which distance I have to place the points along the line to map all houses.

The result is that all house numbers are placed like a string of pearls.

Is there a way to place the numbers with an specific offset along the line?

The script is written in python using arcpy and ArcGIS 10.1 SP1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Geocoding tools. Geocoding will help you to solve 2 problems:

1. *Side offset* (the problem in your question)
2. *End offset* (a new problem that you'll have if you solved *Side offset*)

If you solve *side offset* your map will look like this:
[image]

But near street intersections you will get this new problem:
[image]

To solve this, you will need a second offset – the “end offset”. Then your map will look like this:
[image]

In ArcGIS you can specify Side offset and End offset in [Geocoding options properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Geocoding_options/002500000048000000/).

I suggest that you try this approach:

1. Write a python script to create a table will all addresses. The street shapefile serves as your source file for this.
2. Use the table from step 1 to create Points for all addresses. [See ArcGIS help About geocoding a table of addresses](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_geocoding_a_table_of_addresses/002500000025000000/).

Comment: (+1) on the assumption that the asker will be happy to abandon the work done so far - I had been thinking he had bypassed Geocoding as being unsuitable for his address but maybe he just overlooked it.

Answer (score 4):

In case this is helpful to others, i was able to create the following python code using arcpy which will place points at a specified interval based on an input line feature layer.

```
import arcpy

line_lyr = 'my_line'
pt_lyr =  "my_point"
interval = 200

insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(pt_lyr, ["SHAPE@XY"]) # this is the pre-existing pt feature class

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(line_lyr, ['OID@','SHAPE@','NAME']) as searchCursor: # this is the line feature on which the points will be based
    for row in searchCursor:
        lengthLine = round(row[1].length) # grab the length of the line feature, i'm using round() here to avoid weird rounding errors that prevent the numberOfPositions from being determined
        if int(lengthLine % interval) == 0:
            numberOfPositions = int(lengthLine // interval) - 1
        else:
            numberOfPositions = int(lengthLine // interval)

        print "lengthLine", lengthLine
        print "numberOfPositions", numberOfPositions
        if numberOfPositions > 0: # > 0 b/c we don't want to add a point to a line feature that is less than our interval
            for i in range(numberOfPositions): # using range, allows us to not have to worry about
                distance = (i + 1) * interval
                xPoint = row[1].positionAlongLine(distance).firstPoint.X
                yPoint = row[1].positionAlongLine(distance).firstPoint.Y
                xy = (xPoint, yPoint)
                insertCursor.insertRow([xy])
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would look at **Linear Referencing**, because once you have a **Route Event Layer** of type POINT for your addresses, you should be able to use label offsets to place your event points.

I would recommend taking a quick look at this part of the **[Linear Referencing Tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_4_Displaying_and_querying_route_events/00390000004n000000/)** to see if it sounds like what you are after.  If it does, prototype it through the ArcMap GUI, and then start on the ArcPy code which I *think* should be straight forward.

The key concept is that addresses can be considered as point events referenced along a route representing the street.