# How can i use ihookhelper interface in python?

Tags: python, arcobjects, arcgis-10.0

I use ArcObject in python to develope a tool. I import comtypes in python to access  the arcmap layers in python and use ifeaturelayer interface. I have to set featurelayer to phookhelper.focusmap.get_layer(i) to access the layers in ArcMap. The problem is that I can't find get_layer method in python. Is there any way to access the ArcMap layers in python using ArcObjects?

```
for (int i = 0; i < phookhelper.FocusMap.LayerCount; i++)
            {
                if (phookhelper.FocusMap.get_Layer(i).Name == comboBox1.Text)
                {
                    pfeaturelayer = (IFeatureLayer)phookhelper.FocusMap.get_Layer(i);

                    pfc = pfeaturelayer.FeatureClass;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Layer[i]` instead of `get_Layer(i)`.

Instead of using `IHookHelper` you can get a reference to the ArcMap application, cast it to `IMxApplication` and then get its `FocusMap`.

More pointers here: http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis/upload/misc/python_arcobjects.pdf

Useful helper module here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5082/753

Comment: could you please write the cast code ?

Comment: Like this: `CType(pApp, esriArcMapUI.IMxApplication)` where `CType` is a helper function defined in either of the above links, `pApp` is an `IApplication` reference, and `esriArcMapUI` is a reference to the `comtypes.gen` wrapper around the `esriArcMapUI.olb` library.