# How to use any ArcMap tool from a python script?

Tags: python, arcmap, arcgis-9.3

I'm trying to develop a tool that uses some of arcmap default tools like the `Sketch Tool` or `Trace Tool`. Is it possible?

Let me explain a little more, I need to draw a feature, ask for user input, and save the feature + data to the shape file, can it be done using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need full access to ArcObjects in Python to do this.  See [How do I access arcobjects from python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python).  It is not for the faint of heart.  ESRI uses python as a scripting engine for its geoprocessing tools, not for UI stuff.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not exposed in the Python APIS. If you're feeling intrepid you can try comtypes or writing the functionality in C++ and calling it from ctypes.