# Arcpy and arcobject

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access arcobjects from python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python)

Hi :

I'd like to begin programming with Python in ArcGIS 10 by Arcobject.but i don't have any experience about python and Arcobject relationship and I couldnt fine some good references (websites or books) about this subject . I will be greatly oblige to you if you recommend to me some good referene about this subject .

sincerely

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python

Answer (score 2):

Just a few resources I found with a bit of digging...

http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis/upload/misc/python_arcobjects.pdf
This is a pretty comprehensive presentation about how to use ArcObjects and Arcpy together. It details all the basics for installing comtypes and even performing basic ArcMap functions. Nifty stuff, if you ask me.

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/2567-Accessing-ArcObjects-through-Python
And here is an ESRI post on the subject that mentions a few of the same things as the presentation, as well as containing links to other ESRI forums posts that could prove helpful.

I was not aware just how accessible ArcObjects was through Python until I read this question. +1 for learning something every day. :)