# How can I crawl directory tree and change Mxd relativePaths to true?

Tags: arcpy, file-path

I have a large number of project folders where each project folder can have many subfolders.  These subfolders can contain mxds, shapefiles, personal gdb's and fgdb's.  In many cases the user forgot to check the "Use Relative Paths" before saving the mxds, so when the folder gets copied, datasource links become broken.

I would like to write a standalone arcpy script that crawls through the directories, opens each mxd, sets the relativePaths to true, then saves the mxd.  Is there a script that does this somewhere?

The relativePaths property on the [MapDocument object](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/MapDocument/00s30000000n000000/) is readonly.  Is there some other way to change this?

Comment: I am unsure of this is possible or not using that workflow. But what I do think could work is if you automatically open each .mxd, copy all data sources and information from that original .mxd into a new blank .mxd that has relative paths checked, and then re-save the new one. Just an idea as a work-around if your first way ends up not being possible.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You could get a list of all documents using absolute paths and their authors and SPAM them with a stern e-mail, though.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible using the following python script (with thanks to Neil Clemmons over at the [ESRI forum](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1154&t=260812)). You will need the [comtypes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/comtypes/) library and the [Snippets](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/python_arcobjects.zip) module from Pierssen Consulting.

```
from Snippets import GetLibPath, InitStandalone
from comtypes.client import GetModule, CreateObject
import os

m = GetModule(GetLibPath() + 'esriCarto.olb')
InitStandalone()
file_dir = r'C:\dir'
for filename in os.listdir(file_dir):
   fullpath = os.path.join(file_dir, filename)
   p = CreateObject(m.MapDocument, interface=m.MapDocument)
   p.Open(fullpath)
   newpath = os.path.join(file_dir,'Changed_' + filename)
   p.SaveAs(newpath,True,False)
   del p
```

Comment: Also see the local canonical thread for using Pierssen's Snippets module at [How do I access ArcObjects from Python?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

[Not possible in 10.0](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/32554-Setting-Relative-Paths-Using-Python?p=109608&viewfull=1#post109608), but I have had some success [using ArcObjects in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python) for relatively simple tasks like this where writing a .NET application would be overkill, but the necessary functionality was not exposed in the arcpy/arcgisscripting modules. Use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/os.html#os.walk) for the crawling the directory tree part.

For the ArcObjects bit, use `IMapDocument.Open()` to open the MXD (without having to have it open in ArcMap), cast to `IMxDocument` and set `RelativePaths` to true, and use `IMapDocument.Save()` to save it.

Comment: Have you verified that this _actually_ fixes the paths to relative?

Comment: I have not tried it myself, no, but this thread suggests it should work: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1154&t=260812

Comment: Also I'm sure Kirk already knows how to do this: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=64946 :)

Comment: @blah238 That's VBA, what I need is a standalone arcpy script.

Comment: .net is a very easy way to automate this correction. To say this is not possible is bad info all around.

Comment: The question was in reference to doing this with arcpy, not .NET, and as I understand it's not possible to do with arcpy at 10.0 (see the first link in my answer).

Comment: Also if you noticed I did list an ArcObjects solution, although I'd be interested in hearing your take on it.

Comment: @blah238, thanks for your post. I re-looked at the esri forum post you linked to, and it seems it's only possible within the IMapDocument itself and saveAs. Have answered to say as much