# Install VBA on ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, vba

What is the complete recipe for installing VBA for ArcGIS 10 Desktop?

The [Esri help topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000300000014000000.htm) on this is incomplete. From the number of threads I found troubleshooting this I'm not the only one experiencing difficulties. I've opened a tech support issue, but am still waiting for a response. Perhaps GIS.se is faster?

I have installed the VBA sdk kit from `%install_media%\ArcGIS Desktop 10\SDK_VBA`.
In ArcGIS Desktop Adminstrator I've set license level to Single Use.
Under *Desktop > Availability* VBA is listed as installed but not authorized.
When I run the *[Authorize Now]* wizard VBA is not listed in the available extensions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the Q was about single use, but I might as well round out things out by providing the answer for concurrent licensing use as well so everything is in one place (I don't think it warrants a separate question).

**Prepwork:**

1. Contact your customer support representative, by email, and requestVBA extension authorization (it's free, and no I don't know why you have to ask). Wait.
2. Logon to https://customers.esri.com/, head to "[Authorizations](https://customers.esri.com/#acct_authorizations)". VBA will show in the list, after your service rep adds it.
3. Click on VBA link, you should see a new page with an authorization number. It will look like `ELF1234567890`. Click on that, so that you can get to a page where the text can be selected and copied (2x-click, [ctrl-c]). Also note number of licenses.

**On the license server:**

1. run *ArcGIS License Server Administrator > Authorization > [Authorize Now]*
2. select *"...and need to authorize additional licenses"* and *"ArcGIS Desktop"*, *[next]*
3. select *...using the internet*, *[next]*
4. fill out all the customer profiling info they already have on you, again, *[next]*
5. at the Extensions screen ignore the list presented (3D analyst, etc) and slap *[Other Extensions]*. Fill out info copied from #3, then *[Ok]*, *[next]*, *[finish]*.

   *Feature*     : `VBA`           <-- case sensitive!
    *Auth#*       : `ELF123456890`
    *No. Licenses*: `99`

   1. Back at license server admin main screen verify VBA is listed under *Availability*.

**On each client machine:**

1. install the VBA SDK from the install media (`ArcGIS Desktop 10\SDK_VBA\setup.exe`)
2. In Arcgis Administrator ensure *Concurrent Use* license is selected
3. Run Arcmap and look under *Customize* menu for *VBA Macros*.

**Sources**:

- [using VBA with Arcgis 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000300000014000000.htm)
- you need to use the [Other] button at Extensions page - http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/1628-Beta-10-VBA-license-required?p=37541&viewfull=1#post37541
- typos in Feature still finish successfully, but it's a false message - http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/1131-Beta-10-Anybody-know-how-to-register-VBA-in-Beta-2?p=3844&viewfull=1#post3844

Comment: Hmmmmm...it's almost as if they _want_ to make it hard. Nawww.

Comment: they are making it hard because it will not be in the next version. Even the version 10 VBA is not as integrated as it once was - cannot write global functions and tools, only document level.

Comment: They've moved, and are movign futrther, towards Python with arcpy.  I find it much better than VBA, imo

Comment: @Hairy agreed, python has way more power, flexibility and potential than VBA. However VBA has access to things that arcpy doesn't, unless one [climbs in through the window](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python), and that's not a reliable strategy. I hope that arcpy subsumes everything that used to be VBA, before too long.