# IZ.InterpolateZsBetween, how to use it for multiple parts in polyline

Tags: python, arcobjects

I want to interpolate Z values for the vertexes in the polyline. Shape file contains few polylines. Polylines do have certain vertexes with correct Z value, others do not have Z value (set to ie. 0). As on the picture below.

How do I interpolate (linear interpolation) vertexes with 0 value?

I figured that [IZ.InterpolateZsBetween](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriGeometry/IZ_InterpolateZsBetween.htm) will do that. 
However, with my programming skills at this point, I am able to use basic geoprocessing tools in Python and realy have no clue how to implement ArcObject in it.
Any ideas? 
Any known examples of that kind of code would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IPointCollection http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriGeometry/IPointCollection.htm to loop through all points in the polyline. Your start point is index 0 (presumably it has the right z) and then loop through all the vertices until you find a point with non-zero z. Then that becomes your end point and you call InterpolateZsbetween. Then you reset you start point to be the end point you just used and keep looping.

Make sure you handle the special cases like avoiding to call InterpolateZsbetween when i is your start index and i + 1 is your end index (hint you just want to set start index to i + 1 and keep going...

Comment: Well, all this seems pretty straight forward while I read it. Knowing my Object Orientated Programming skills, I know that it will be tricky. Thanks a lot, Ragi. Do you have may be a any/similar code, which uses ArcObjects in Ptyhon? I found it the best way to learn by looking at examples, but unfortunately I can't find much re: ArcObjects in Python. Only VBA...

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python