# Using ArcPy for Copy Parallel, Move, etc (from Editor toolbar)?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcgis-desktop

Since VB can activate the Editor, then use the tools listed in the Editor, such as copy parrallel, I am wondering whether Python can do the same job? I have been searching the website all day. Still can't find the answer from early questions-and-answers.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The arcpy library is a stripped down, coarse-grained subset of the functionality exposed by ArcObjects. If you want to run editing commands you'll need to use ArcObjects. If you want to use Python for this, check out the question [How do I access ArcObjects from Python?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I will look at the ArcObjects.

Answer (score 1):

If you have upgraded to ArcGIS 10.1 or beyond then you can perform a Move equivalent in ArcPy using **arcpy.da.UpdateCursor** and the **SHAPE@XY** token as described in **[this Answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65959/how-to-move-offset-point-locations-using-modelbuilder-or-arcpy/65968#65968)** to another Question.

I have not tried emulating Copy Parallel but I suspect that it can do that too using the same method.