# Moving / offsetting point locations using ArcPy or ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, geometry, cursor

I have a number non-georeferenced CAD layers (see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65654/how-to-convert-a-visio-diagram-to-a-gis-layer/65771#65771)) that have text annotation features.  I have created a model to convert the text to points, but after converting the annotation to a Point featureclass, I see that the CAD text anchor points do not coincide with the center of the CAD text (which is where the points belong).

Therefore, I would like to **programatically** (using ArcPy or ModelBuilder) [[move] a feature relative to its current location (delta x,y)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/relative_to_its_current_location_delta_x_y/01m80000000s000000/) using a measured X,Y value that I will provide.

This would allow me to move the GIS points back to where they belong, instead of the offset CAD anchor point.

How can I accomplish this task?

---

@PolyGeo gave an excellent [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/65968/115) using *SHAPE@XY* IN 10.1, but currently I am running 10.0.  Any 10.0 ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I credit @artwork21 for leading me to my final solution.  I actually found a nearly complete script in the ArcGIS 10.0 online help article called "[Calculate Field examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004s000000)", listed under the subcategory "*Code samples—geometry*" and "*For a point feature class, shift the x coordinate of each point by 100*"

The final script that I used within the ModelBuilder "Calculate Field" tool was:

Expression:

```
shiftXYCoordinates(!SHAPE!,%ShiftX%,%ShiftY%)
```

where *ShiftX* and *ShiftY* are variables (as parameters) defined on the ModelBuilder canvas.

Expression Type:

```
PYTHON_9.3
```

Code Block:

```
def shiftXYCoordinates(shape,x_shift,y_shift):
   point = shape.getPart(0)
   point.X += float(x_shift)
   point.Y += float(y_shift)
   return point
```

Since all models work on a selected set, you should also be able to create this as a generic tool that will work in conjunction with other models/tools in other modelbuilder sessions. The very simple model I created (as a "plugin" to other models to shift coordinate values) looks like this.  That way I can control the shift on a per-selection-set basis (as defined in other models):

[image: ShiftXY Model]

It worked like a charm, thank you all for your input!

Comment: is it possible to shift feature by the value inside table, stored in column?

Comment: It should be.  Just assign the ShiftX and ShiftY parameters to the appropriate columns.

Comment: I'm confused by what you are passing in here as "shape". Can you help me out please?

Comment: The "Expression" shows the parameters that are being passed into the code-block function called shiftXYCoordinates().  So the first parameter is !SHAPE!, which is the shape field from the layer.

Answer (score 17):

This code should do it using the SHAPE@XY token that came with [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000) in ArcGIS 10.1.

```
import arcpy
# Set some variables
fc = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFC"
fc2 = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFCcopy"
xOffset = 0.001
yOffset = 0.001
# Code to make a copy which will have its coordinates moved (and can be compared with original)
if arcpy.Exists(fc2):
    arcpy.Delete_management(fc2)
arcpy.Copy_management(fc,fc2)
# Perform the move
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, ["SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + xOffset,row[0][1] + yOffset]])
```

The coding pattern used here came from [ArcPy Café](http://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/shifting-features/).

Comment: Ugh!  It took me until this morning to realize that _SHAPE@XY_ is only available in 10.1, and my company is still using 10.0.  This is a great answer (going forward), but I'm going to wait and see if anyone has any suggestions for 10.0.  Thanks!

Comment: More information on a similar process for anybody reading this. Still 10.1.  http://arcpy.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/disperse-overlapping-points/

Comment: Is this actually setting the values anywhere? Never used the UpdateCursor like that before. Usually I do += and then update the row. Otherwise only thing I do different in my version is the UpdateCursor uses ['SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y'] so you can access them as row[0] and row[1] instead of having to do the row[0][0] and row[0][1]. Think its just a bit easier to read for me.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid way to update the rows. Actually, I had never seen a value passed in updateRow() until a few weeks ago. It was actually an example for updating the geometry.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer PolyGeo! I was actually pretty impressed that the code worked without modifications.  I'm running ArcGIS Desktop 10.6

Answer (score 5):

You may also use [this field calculator script](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2011/12/06/how-to-update-the-location-of-a-point-feature-and-its-xy-fields/) to move feature locations:

```
def XYsetVALUE( shape, X_value, Y_value): 
  myMoveX = 0.001
  myMoveY = 0.001
  point = shape.getPart(0) 
  point.X = X_value + myMoveX
  point.Y = Y_value + myMoveY
  return point
```

XYsetVALUE ( !SHAPE!, !X_COORD!, !Y_COORD! )

You could include an extra Calculate Field method within your model using the function above.

Comment: Thats an interesting way to do it, I didn't actually know you could field calculate on the shape field. This may actually be the easiest way to get it done if it is a set offset for all points. It would probably be faster to do point.X += myMoveX and point.Y += myMoveY instead of needing to pass in X and Y coordinates for it though.

Answer (score 5):

I adapted the solution to move / shift points point into a certain direction (angle) and a given distance.

Looks like:

```
def shiftXYCoordinates(shape,angle,distance):
point = shape.getPart(0)
point.Y += distance * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
point.X += distance * math.sin(math.radians(angle))
return point
```

and be called like shiftXYCoordinates(!SHAPE!, !Angle! ,5000), if you have a field “angle” for your points features (or with a constant of course).
Angle should be given in decimal degrees. 0 will shift “up”, 90 “right” etc. I got them after creating strip map index features and converting those to points.

Also make sure to select Field Name “Shape” before running :)

(Solution tested in ArcMap 10.0 SP5)

Answer (score 4):

As you can see, it's a lot easier in 10.1 when you get access to cursor tokens.

```
import arcpy
# Code to move features in copy of same dataset
fc = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFC"
fc2 = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFCcopy"
xOffset = 0.001
yOffset = 0.001
if arcpy.Exists(fc2):
    arcpy.Delete_management(fc2)
arcpy.Copy_management(fc, fc2)

shape = arcpy.Describe(fc2).ShapeFieldName

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc2)
for row in cursor:    
    point = row.getValue(shape).getPart()
    row.setValue(shape, arcpy.Point(point.X + xOffset, point.Y + yOffset))
    cursor.updateRow(row) 

del point, row, cursor
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for 10.0:

```
# Featureclass here
FC = r'featureclass'

fcount = 0
shapefield = arcpy.Describe(FC).shapeFieldName
featureUpdate = arcpy.UpdateCursor(FC)
for f in featureUpdate:
    # Hard coded shifts but easy enough to set up a lookup function if needed
    sLon = 0.001
    sLat = 0.001
    # Optional but I like to count to see where it is at in the process
    if fcount % 1000 == 0:
        print('Updating feature %s...' %(fcount))
    # Get the original value
    cF = f.getValue(shapefield)
    cPNT = cF.getPart()
    # Create a new point with the shifted value
    sPNT = arcpy.Point(cPNT.X - sLon, cPNT.Y - sLAT)
    # Set the shapefield to the new point and update feature
    f.setValue(shapefield, sPNT)
    featureUpdate.updateRow(f)
    fcount += 1
del featureUpdate
```