# Is it possible to move/shift an annotation to a new XY using Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, annotation

Real quick question, I was wondering if it is possible to move/shift an annotation to a new XY using Python.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  10.0 answer is no (or not easily) but 10.1/10.2 can do it.

Comment: I am using 10.0 (I may have access to higher versions), but how do you do that in 10.1/10.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2, I do not think there is any straightforward way to move annotation features using ArcPy/Python.  I had hoped that this could be done using the **SHAPE@XY** tokens of **arcpy.da.UpdateCursor** but at **[Python Café](http://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/shifting-features/)** an Esri response says:

> Unfortunately, our cursors currently don’t have support for updating
>   or inserting annotation features.

If converting your annotation to point features (that you then label) is a viable workaround for you then the **[Q&A here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65959/how-to-move-offset-point-locations-using-modelbuilder-or-arcpy)** will provide 10.0 - 10.2 solutions.