# Editing coordinates of some point features in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, arcgis-10.3

I am working on a point shapefile in ArcGIS 10.3, now I have to move some of the points to new locations based on another point shapefile, I have already tried it by using Editor/Edit vertices and dragging specific point to the exact location based on the second point shapefile. They are successfully moved to new location however when I am adding the coordinates (Long and Lat) to the attribute table of the respective shapefile, the values are Zero! So how can I get the coordinates for edited points?

Comment: In arcgis a dataset has a shape field this is the geometry, in your case your points. Any other fields have been added by someone. Your lat/long fields are *not* live links to the geometry field so it's not surprising that new points are zero and moved ones have not updated. You need recompute those fields if you want to see values. The add XY coordinates in the answer below is what you need to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *Add XY Coordinates* (Data Management > Features > Add XY Coordinates).

[image]

Considering that your shapes are properly projected. However, you need not to drag it to specific coordinate. In Edit Vertices mode, right click on the point and select *move to* option.

[image]

Comment: Dear @blu_sr thanks for your answer, Now I am trying Move to option however it's taking too much time because I have around 100 points for editing. I was thinking if there was a way to get the coordinates of dragged points, it could be less time consuming.

Comment: You also have to spatial ajustement possibility to move points. You should also check you are indeed in lat/long by clearing the coordinate system in the layer properties and looking at the coordinate displayed. If it's around 0, you might not be in the system you think you are, thus having wrong coordinates.

Comment: the points should update their coordinate once they are saved. You may have to use Python to batch edit your points. If you have the 'to coordinate' listed use it write you existing shape. Try [this example](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65959/how-to-move-offset-point-locations-using-modelbuilder-or-arcpy).

Comment: @RobinP thanks, there is not anything wrong with the coordinate system.

Comment: @blu_sr I 'm beginner in Phyton and do not have enough time to try the code because I am getting ready for my PhD dissertation, however I would try it when I am free. Now, just doing the first method you have posted earlier. Best Regards