# moving the objects in a feature class by a field within the table of that feature class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I have a feature class and I want to move its objects based on two fields in it I used the following code but get error:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2,["SHAPE@XY","centerpo_4","centerpo_5"]) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    XM=row[1]
    YM=row[2]

    cursor.updateRow([row[0][0]+ XM,row[0][1]+YM])
```

The columns "centerpo_4","centerpo_5" are two fields within the feature class. 
When I run the code I encounter with following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\Rezars\Desktop\test2.py", line 34, in <module>
cursor.updateRow([row[0][0]+ XM,row[0][1]+YM])
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

The number of objects in the table are 2893 (FID starts from 0)which all three columns have the same row numbers(2893).

[image: This the images of attribute table of my feature class]

Comment: It simply expects a full list of row fields that you defined. row [0] i.e. SHAPE@XY gives/expects you a xy tuple, be aware.

Comment: I have got this code from :http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65959/how-to-move-offset-point-locations-using-modelbuilder-or-arcpy

Comment: it works when I use fixed values but gives error when I want to use the values in the table as variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do won't work as you're not passing back the same information as you asked in your cursor - `["SHAPE@XY", "centerpo_4", "centerpo_5"]` - it is expecting three values back.  This is why you're getting the error

```
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

First you need to pass your new XY **to row[0]** as a tuple.  As your other two values are unchanged, you can just modify the `SHAPE@XY` tuple value and pass the others back unchanged by passing the entire `row` object.  Untested, but I would try something like the following:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, ["SHAPE@XY", "centerpo_4", "centerpo_5"]) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    newX = row[0][0] + row[1]
    newY = row[0][1] + row[2]
    row[0] = (newX, newY)

    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: It worked and I learned some thing from you. I really appreciate for your help dear Midavalo