# Using commands from ArcMap Main Menu in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

Is it possible to use the functions from ArcMap's Main Menu (for example Add Data, Start Editing) in my model?

I cannot find a way to add any other functions except Toolboxes.

Comment: What functions do you want to use from ArcMap menu? Main idea of ModelBuilder is to apply some processing tasks (geoprocessing) to input data and receive output.

Comment: Tools that support edit sessions piggyback onto the existing edit session. It is not possible without using ArcObjects to start/stop an edit session programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually one hacky method. To use COM objects in Python and in this way to communicate with ArcObjects.

There was already such topic here: [How do I access ArcObjects from Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python).

Read also this presentation: [Using ArcObjects in Python](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis/upload/misc/python_arcobjects.pdf).

and this thread on Esri forum: [ArcMap 10, ArcObjects, and Python: very cool, but help with a couple of problems?](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/15848-ArcMap-10-ArcObjects-and-Python-very-cool-but-help-with-a-couple-of-problems)