# Reloading cache on open Attribute Table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table, refresh

I used python to update a shapeFile through cursors.  The Shapefile is updated, but there could be an open Attribute Table.

Manually you can hit "reload cache" to update the Attribute Table and see the changes.  I would like the python script to reload the cache, so the user does not have to remember to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try the easy things first, like clearing and resetting the [Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000008000000)'s definition query or resetting its data source with the [`arcpy.mapping`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Introduction_to_arcpy_mapping/00s300000032000000/) module. Failing that you could use [ArcObjects in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python) to refresh the table view via [ITableWindow](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ITableWindow_Interface/000v0000018r000000/).Refresh.

Comment: I wonder if the arcpy.RefreshActiveView() would work in his script.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
    import arcpy

    definition_query = layer.definitionQuery
    # Change the Definition Query into something different
    if definition_query == '':
        oid = arcpy.ListFields(dataset = layer, field_type = 'OID')[0]
        layer.definitionQuery = '{} > 0'.format(oid.name)
    else:
        layer.definitionQuery = ''
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    # Restore the Definition Query
    layer.definitionQuery = definition_query
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```