# Reload Table Cache with Python & ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-addin

I am trying to create a button in arcmap that reloads the table cache. Exactly, like the existing button Table Options > Reload Cache. The button is inside when you open an attribute table. I would like to create a custom button that is in a toolbar I made. I tried to search for tools in customization and it isn't present nor could I find any sample code for this.

I have a custom Python Addin Toolbar with comboboxes that manipulates data in a database and since it doesn't update the data upon selection I would like another way to refresh with having to close the table and reopen and//or selecting the existing tool.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59994/how-to-refresh-open-attribute-table-in-arcmap-using-arcpy-rather-than-arcobjects](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59994/how-to-refresh-open-attribute-table-in-arcmap-using-arcpy-rather-than-arcobjects)

Comment: It looks like the only way to do this is programmatically is with ArcObjects still. I didn't see any ArcGIS Ideas specific to refreshing tables with arcpy, but there are a few related to refreshing tables after using various editing or GP tools: http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000brwO http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008KMi

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59994/how-to-refresh-open-attribute-tabl‌​e-in-arcmap-using-arcpy-rather-than-arcobjects this doesn't work. Blah238 thanks for your comment. This is what I got back from ESRI.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate whuber. The previous question was not answered. If you actually read the questions you will know they are different, not the mention the code provided doesn't apply to refreshing tables. Thanks for nothing.