# Updating attribute table of shapefile on display automatically using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I have a shapefile attribute table on display. After some processing, I have to right click click Refresh to get updated version of table. I am wondering if there is a way using arcpy to update it automatically every time I make an edit to shapefile.

Note: I have a dialog box with values which I change based on my requirement and press recalculation which gives me updated attribute table.

Comment: Have you looked into my question here - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59994/how-to-refresh-open-attribute-table-in-arcmap-using-arcpy-rather-than-arcobjects? If I remember right, the table is updated when in the editing session (you can start it with arcpy).

Comment: So if i use field calculator within a class of my Add-In then the table will be updated automatically?

Comment: If I remember right, yes, but you have to be in the editing session.