# Creating ArcGIS toolbar with new tools using Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, python-addin, toolbar

I have written a number of fairly-simple python functions using `arcpy` which help a user significantly when performing a certain workflow using various tools (both ArcGIS toolbox tools and external software).

I'd really like to bind some of these functions to buttons on a new ArcGIS toolbar, as they are not really geoprocessing tools, but more like 'Workflow Management Tools', as they do things like show and hide various layers, change symbologies etc, and generally make it easier for the user to perform specific tasks.

Is there a way to do this? I have looked in the documentation and have found various things about how to create toolbar buttons using ArcObjects, and I have found [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python) about accessing ArcObjects from Python, but I'm not sure how easily these can be combined.

Does anyone know if this can be done, and if so, how?

Comment: Do your scripts need to communicate with the current ArcMap session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you can create a new toolbar with Buttons/Tools/etc on it, based on Python using ArcGIS 10.1 Addins.  You should be able to take advantage of your current Python code and integrate it in these new tools.

Take a look, it is fairly simple to create.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_add_in/014p00000025000000/