# ArcObjects/VBA to python Network edge to junction lookup IEdgeFeature equivalent in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, geometric-network

In an effort to migrate a script that transfers attributes from a geometric network to a feature class (on a given network edge segment, what are the up and downstream junctions?) I would like to determine what the equivalent function in python for the following VBA/.Net [IEdgeFeature](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000001zn000000) Interface:

- FromJunctionFeature
- ToJunctionFeature

Answer (score 2):

ArcPy is not and was never intended to be functionally equivalent to ArcObjects. This is one of those things I think you need ArcObjects for.

You will probably want to look into .NET/Java add-in development or, what I think would be cool and assuming you are at 10.1, is using [Python add-ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000025000000) and [ArcObjects in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python?lq=1).

Don't think I've seen anyone make one yet though so you'd be the first :)