# ArcObjects + comtypes at 10.1 and newer

Tags: python, arcobjects, comtypes

Has anyone played around with [using ArcObjects in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python?) at version 10.1?

I am having all sorts of problems, such as `TypeError`s when wrapping the ESRI OLB modules and `AttributeError`s when attempting to use a method or property of a wrapped module.

Anyone had any better luck?

Comment: I removed the 10.1 version specific tag because this same error and fix applies to 10.1, 10.2, and 10.3 (and we don't have a 10.x tag). Also it doesn't need *arcgis* tag as there aren't any *arcobjects* without it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of July 2015 [release 1.1.2](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.comtypes.user/681) comtypes has the patch from below applied. :) Install using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) from PyPi or from github:

```
pip install comtypes

pip install https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/archive/master.zip
```

---

There is a fix for this, taken from the ArcGIS Forums: [10.1 beta and comtypes](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/43583-10.1-beta-and-comtypes). Edit *comtypes* module, under `PYTHONPATH\lib\site-packages`  and add the following entry to the `_ctype_to_vartype` dictionary in `automation.py`:

> ```
> POINTER(BSTR): VT_BYREF|VT_BSTR,
> ```

You may also need to delete `automation.pyc`, `automation.pyo`, `safearray.pyc`, and `safearray.pyo` in the same folder.

Also see page 5 of Mark Cederholm's 2012 Dev Summit presentation: [ArcMap and Python: Closing the VBA Gap](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/arcmap_and_python.pdf), and in the header of his updated snippets modules for [10.0](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/snippets100.py), [10.1](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/snippets101.py) and [10.2](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/snippets102.py) respectively; index page: http://pierssen.com/arcgis10/python.htm

---

<s>There is a [pull request](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/pull/75) to merge the patch into master comtypes; still open because Enthought (rightly) won't apply patches without accompanying tests.</s>

Comment: +1 Unfortunately, this doesn't fix everything, though. calling `comtypes.client.GetModule` on esriDataSourcesOleDB.olb, esriGlobeCoreUI.olb, and esriSchematicControls.olb still generates attribute errors. Furthermore, the coclasses that should be accessible in esriFramework.olb (such as AppROT), aren't.

Comment: Anyone tried this fix for 10.2 with results?

Comment: Works fine for me with the above fix.

Comment: Fix above worked for me in 10.2, Thanks @blah238

Comment: I submitted a pull request to the comtypes project on GitHub: https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/pull/75. If this fix is applied upstream we won't need to do this anymore.

Comment: @mattwilkie Sorry this fell off the radar, but it looks good to me now! Thanks! Also that would be great if they fixed it in comtypes itself. Didn't know they were on GitHub now.

Answer (score 1):

To gain access to arcobjects (10.1) via python I had to delete `automation.pyc, automation.pyo, safearray.pyc` and `safearray.pyo` in the **comtypes** directory. I also deleted all of the files in the `C:\Users\USER_ID\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\comtypes_cache` and had to change the

ProductList = `[esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo, esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeArcEditor, esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeArcView]`

to 
`[esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced, esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeStandard, esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic]`.

The last thing that I did was search the syntax for all “10.0” strings and replaced them with “10.1”.

Comment: An alternative to deleting the cache manually is to (re)create the cache with `comtypes.client.GetModule( 'filename.olb' )`. See https://github.com/maphew/arcplus/blob/master/arcplus/ao/test.py (worked for me, may not elsewhere).