# Seeking Python script for creating .mxd files?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, map-service

I am new to both ArcGIS and Python. My requirement is to automate the below MANUAL process:

1. Creating a layer in ArcGIS for Desktop. To put it in another words, creating an ArcMap document (.mxd).
2. Publishing the created ArcMap document (in Step 1) as a service to ArcGIS Server.

Currently we are doing this manually. I have come across scripts to automate step 2 using Python.

How can I automate step 1 and step 2?

Answer (score 16):

This isn't really a standalone answer, more of an addition to [@PolyGeo's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/50715/2856) as it addresses the 'mxd creation from scratch' in python issue.

You can create MXD's from scratch in python if you [access ArcObjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/80/2856). You will need the [comtypes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/comtypes) package and if using ArcGIS 10.1, you need to make a small change to `automation.py`. See [ArcObjects + comtypes at 10.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37673/753)

Below is some code to create an MXD from scratch in python:

```
import arcpy
import comtypes,os

def CreateMXD(path):
    GetModule('esriCarto.olb')
    import comtypes.gen.esriCarto as esriCarto
    pMapDocument = CreateObject(esriCarto.MapDocument, esriCarto.IMapDocument)
    pMapDocument.New(path)
    pMapDocument.Save() #probably not required...

def GetLibPath():
    """ Get the ArcObjects library path

        It would be nice to just load the module directly instead of needing the path,
        they are registered after all... But I just don't know enough about COM to do this

    """
    compath=os.path.join(arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['InstallDir'],'com')
    return compath

def GetModule(sModuleName):
    """ Generate (if not already done) wrappers for COM modules
    """
    from comtypes.client import GetModule
    sLibPath = GetLibPath()
    GetModule(os.path.join(sLibPath,sModuleName))

def CreateObject(COMClass, COMInterface):
    """ Creates a new comtypes POINTER object where
        COMClass is the class to be instantiated,
        COMInterface is the interface to be assigned
    """
    ptr = comtypes.client.CreateObject(COMClass, interface=COMInterface)
    return ptr

if __name__=='__main__':
    #testing...
    arcpy.SetProduct('arcview')
    filepath='c:/temp/testing123.mxd'
    if os.path.exists(filepath):os.unlink(filepath)
    CreateMXD(filepath)
```

Answer (score 13):

Sample code to Create a layer in ArcGIS for Desktop is on the Online Help for [AddLayer (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000025000000).

The steps for Publishing an ArcMap document as a service to ArcGIS for Server are in the Online Help for [Publishing a map service with Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq000000nw000000).

Note that it is not possible to create an MXD using ArcPy - you need to have an existing MXD to which you can add layers.  That design decision is described in the Online Help on [Guidelines for arcpy.mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000006s000000) , but being able to create a new Map Document from nothing in ArcPy is an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004VTpIAM) that I would like to see implemented.

See [@Luke's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/50718/115) for an advanced Python and ArcObjects method that I have not tested but may provide you with a workaround for creating an MXD from a Python script that ArcPy can then go on to manipulate.