# Creating custom forms in ArcMap

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, vba

I am hoping to make a custom form within ArcMap 10.3 where the end user can select a recently digitized shapefile (or feature), and enter values of specific attributes through a custom form. This form would also validate the entries based on parameters. I have been told that VB is no longer supported for ArcMap 10.x.

Is this true, then how do I create such a form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBA is still available in 10.x, but must be installed separately.  Prior to 10.x, it was included with installation files.  Now, however, you must install separately and receive a license for the VBA extension (it's free, but you must request it from ESRI).

Aside from VBA, there are other ways to create custom UI elements, including [.NET](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/) and [python](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/what-is-a-python-add-in.htm) addins.  The python addins are limited compared to .NET capabilities.  For a custom form, you'll probably need to go with .NET.  Read [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67279/what-are-pros-and-cons-of-python-add-ins-vs-net-add-ins-to-arcgis-for-desktop) for more discussion.