# How can I pan an ArcGIS map from an external application?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop

I have a web application with geocoded addresses.  I would like to be able to click on an address within that application, and have ArcMap 10 respond by panning the map to the corresponding location.

Is there some sort of API or Python script that could accomplish this task?  I imagine my application would work similarly to Skype, and have a link to an address like:

`arcgis://46.52,-84.46`

where `arcgis` is the application, and `46.52,-84.46` are the coordinates to pan to.

I may be reaching pretty far here, but perhaps someone has tried to do this before.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no API to do this out of the box, but maybe it could be accomplished through a 3rd application that [registers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx) your [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme), handles those URIs, and [remotely controls ArcMap through ArcObjects](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/56eba175-54c1-46b4-801a-fc968e582581.htm).

If you want to use Python and ArcObjects for this see this question: [Accessing ArcObjects from Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/80/753)

I don't think this is for the faint of heart, though. Good luck.