# Handle annotation layers with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, annotation

I want to access annotation layers using arcpy (the purpose is to verify few text strings in text annotations). By annotation I mean **draw tool annotations**, not dynamic labels. These annotation layers are under a groups layer by the name of 'Default'.

The [Esri documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000) talks of draw annotation as being layers themselves :

> There are essentially three categories of layers in a map document: feature layers, group layers, and raster layers. The isFeatureLayer, isGroupLayer, and isRasterLayer properties allow you to identify or isolate the majority of layer types but not all layer types. ***There are a few specialized layers and datasets that don't fall into one of these three categories: annotation subclasses, dimension features, network datasets, terrain datasets, topology datasets, and so on. In these cases you may need to test other properties to isolate a layer of interest before doing something to it.***

One thing to be aware of is [how ArcGIS handles draw annotations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000021000000), two mean configurations are possible :

> ArcGIS fully supports two types of annotation: geodatabase and map document

In my case, it's map document.

---

In light of all this documentation, it so appears that draw annotations are mere layers, thus a simple code such as this should be working :

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("some\mxdpath\here")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"current_annotation_layer",df)
```

But the problem is the annotations do not seem obtainable via dataframe (which is weird considering each of my annotation layers is associated to a feature layer).

---

Is there any specific ArcPy class to access annotations (one comparable to [IAnnotationFeature2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000206000000) of ArcObject SDK)?

Comment: Did you manage to modify your map document annotation group via comptypes and ArcObjects? Any pointers for further info? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArcPy does not expose all of ArcObjects. From what I can tell, this is one of the many interfaces that are not exposed in ArcPy. Only Page Layout elements are exposed in arcpy: [ListLayoutElements (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ListLayoutElements/00s30000003w000000/)

If you need to do this your only choice is ArcObjects. If you want to use Python, see [How do I access ArcObjects from Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/80/753)

Otherwise you might want to look for or create an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com) about this (the only relevant existing idea I found was [this one](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008Erj)).

Comment: Hi, I was sort of expecting this answer, but thanks and +1 for the links, this might help.

Comment: @Akheloes Did you manage to modify your map document annotation group via comptypes and ArcObjects?

Answer (score 1):

Annotations ARE accessible via arcpy and can be treated as layers. The code didn't work because it's missing an index, NOT because annotations aren't accessible. These functions return a list every time, so even if you are using a wildcard (in this case "**Layers**" and "**current_annotation_layer**"), you still need to specify the index to retrieve it and assign it to an object (**df** & **lyr** respectively).

Code should be:

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "current_annotation_layer", df)[0]
```

Here's an example I used arcpy to access my annotation layer. For my map, I wanted the annotation to be moved below a mask with 20% transparency if it was outside my area of interest.

```
my_annotation_lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("Long_ProjectsAnno")
reference_lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("counties_mask")
arcpy.mapping.MoveLayer(df, reference_lyr, my_annotation_lyr, "AFTER")
```