# Searching multiple MXDs and identifying which have graphics elements using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, mxd, graphics

How would I go about identifying all the mxd files that have graphics?

I reckon it's close to:

```
import arcpy
import os

srcPath = "my_path"

mxd_lst = [f for f in os.listdir(srcPath) if f.endswith('.mxd')]

for mxd in mxd_lst:
    for dfrm in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):

        if "GRAPHIC_ELEMENT" in dfrm != None:  # *I'm making this line up*
            print(mxd + " has graphic elements")

        else:
            print(mxd + " does not contain graphics")
```

Answer (score 4):

`arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements` is what you need. See [the docs](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.8/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayoutelements.htm) for more info on other element types (e.g. text-elements)

I modified your code slightly.

```
import arcpy
import os

srcPath = r"\\somePath\to\MapFiles"

mxd_lst = [os.path.join(srcPath, f) for f in os.listdir(srcPath) if f.lower().endswith('.mxd')]

mxds_with_graphicElms = []
for mxdPath in mxd_lst:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
    graphicElms = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "GRAPHIC_ELEMENT", "*")
    if graphicElms:
        mxds_with_graphicElms.append(mxdPath)
        print(mxdPath + " has graphic elements")
        
print (str(mxds_with_graphicElms))
```

Comment: Cheers. Runs well. As a point of clarification, ListLayoutElements searches dataframes  well as layouts?

Comment: No, you may be mixing up ArcPro and ArcMap terminology. In ArcMap, to search Dataframes, use the `arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames()` method. This will only find data frame objects. Once the DF is identified, then you could do a nested for loop with, for example, arcpy.mapping.ListLayers().

Comment: Unlikely, but possible. To clarify: in an ArcMap 10.7 GUI, "Data View" would be proper, but one would Insert > Data Frame. In standalone Python, mapping.ListDataFrames accesses the same objects. A layout is a layout since the ArcView days. By 'graphics', I mean objects created with the Draw toolbar...whose display is controlled as a matter of annotation in the Frame properties, but if converting to features (e.g. via right-clicking the Data Frame in the TOC), one selects "Convert Graphics to Features". I'm interested in point graphics in any frame, hence nested FOR loops in original post.

Comment: I see. I do not believe ArcPy has access to map-annotation elements. Certainly `listLayoutElements` does not. Per ESRI: "ListLayoutElements only returns elements from a page layout and not map annotation elements that may exist within a data frame."   https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayoutelements.htm

Comment: Also check out the answer from @blah238 here: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89582/handle-annotation-layers-with-arcpy)