# Multithreading in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, multithreading

I am learning multithreading and thinking about using it with Arcpy. The example I am working on doesn't have much practical reasons. However, I don't know why it fails on the line "arcpy.Exists(fcPath):" even though the SDE is running and the feature class in question is accessible in ArcCatalog. It didn't help if I used env.workspace.

```
import threading
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

def tf(conn_string):
    global tTotal
    #env.workspace = conn_string
    fcName = r"GIS_USER.TEST_FC"
    fcPath = conn_string + "\\" + fcName
    if arcpy.Exists(fcPath):
        threadLock.acquire()
        tTotal += 1
        threadLock.release()       
    else:
        print('%d: failed to connect to %s'%(tTotal, conn_string))

def mt(conn_string, step): 
    global tTotal 
    thread_list = []

    for num in range(step):
        t = threading.Thread(target=tf, args=(conn_string,))
        thread_list.append(t)
        t.start()

    for t in thread_list: 
        t.join()

    print "total = %d"%tTotal    

tTotal = 0
conn_string = r"C:\test_conn.sde"
threadLock = threading.Lock()
mt(conn_string, 5)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This just plain won't work, you're going to need to look into [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) if you want parallelism. ArcGIS Desktop/Server's architecture is based on the [COM Single-Threaded Apartment model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), meaning that any objects created on one thread can only be used on that thread. You can create [a new ArcObjects object graph on another thread (see the linked documentation)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000100000000), at which point you'd need to use [`comtypes`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python?) on the other thread(s) and use ArcObjects via the API generated by `comtypes`. This isn't for the faint of heart.