# Build network dataset using comtypes and arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, comtypes

I am aware of the existence of this [Build Network Dataset with python comtypes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109779/build-network-dataset-with-python-comtypes][1]) question. In fact, I used the same code. The error I am getting is different hence my posting of this new question. I am using Arcmap 10.3. Here's my code:

```
from Snippets import *
import arcpy, os  

def create_nd(gdb):  
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Network')  
    GetModule('esriGeoDatabase.olb')  
    GetModule('esriDataSourcesGDB.olb')  
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase  
    import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesGDB as esriDataSourcesGDB  

    # create new empty data element for buildable network dataset  
    nd = NewObj(esriGeoDatabase.DENetworkDataset,  
                esriGeoDatabase.IDENetworkDataset2)  
    nd.Buildable = True  
    nd.NetworkType = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkDatasetType(1)  

    # open feature dataset and create IGeoDataset interface  
    pWSF = NewObj(esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory, esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)  
    gdbWSF = CType(pWSF, esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)  
    print gdbWSF.WorkspaceDescription, gdbWSF.WorkspaceType  
    gdbFWS = CType(gdbWSF.OpenFromFile(gdb, 0), esriGeoDatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)  
    print gdbFWS  
    openFWS = gdbFWS.OpenFeatureDataset('Transportation')  
    fdsGDS = CType(openFWS, esriGeoDatabase.IGeoDataset)  
    print fdsGDS  

    # copy feature dataset's extent and spatial reference to network dataset element  
    deGDS = CType(nd, esriGeoDatabase.IDEGeoDataset)  
    deGDS.Extent = fdsGDS.Extent  
    deGDS.SpatialReference = fdsGDS.SpatialReference  
    print deGDS.Extent  

    # get flow lines  
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(gdb, 'Transportation')  
    lines = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*', 'Polyline')[2]    

    # create data element  
    dataElement = CType(nd, esriGeoDatabase.IDataElement)  
    dataElement.Name = 'Streets_ND'  
    print dataElement.Name  

    # specify edge features  
    edgeNet = NewObj(esriGeoDatabase.EdgeFeatureSource,  
                     esriGeoDatabase.INetworkSource)  
    edgeNet.Name = lines  
    edgeNet.ElementType = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkElementType(2)   

    #set edge feature's connectivity (Any Vertex)  
    edgeFS = CType(edgeNet, esriGeoDatabase.IEdgeFeatureSource)  
    edgeFS.UsesSubtypes = False  
    edgeFS.ClassConnectivityGroup = 1  
    edgeFS.ClassConnectivityPolicy = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkEdgeConnectivityPolicy(0) # any vertex  


    # add sources and sinks as junctions  
    # make origins  
    sinkNet = NewObj(esriGeoDatabase.JunctionFeatureSource,  
                     esriGeoDatabase.INetworkSource)  
    sinkNet.Name = 'Sinks'  
    sinkNet.ElementType = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkElementType(1)   

    # set connectivity  
    sinkElm = CType(sinkNet, esriGeoDatabase.IJunctionFeatureSource)  
    sinkElm.UsesSubtypes = False  
    sinkElm.ClassConnectivityGroup = 1  
    sinkElm.ClassConnectivityPolicy = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkJunctionConnectivityPolicy(0) # honor  

    # make destinations  
    sourceNet = NewObj(esriGeoDatabase.JunctionFeatureSource,  
                     esriGeoDatabase.INetworkSource)  
    sourceNet.Name = 'Sources'  
    sourceNet.ElementType = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkElementType(1)   

    # set connectivity  
    sourceElm = CType(sourceNet, esriGeoDatabase.IJunctionFeatureSource)  
    sourceElm.UsesSubtypes = False  
    sourceElm.ClassConnectivityGroup = 1  
    sourceElm.ClassConnectivityPolicy = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkJunctionConnectivityPolicy(0) # honor  

    # add attributes (Length, Cost, Units)  
    evalNetAttr = NewObj(esriGeoDatabase.EvaluatedNetworkAttribute,  
                         esriGeoDatabase.IEvaluatedNetworkAttribute)  
    newAttr2 = CType(evalNetAttr, esriGeoDatabase.INetworkAttribute2)  
    newAttr2.Name = 'METERS'  
    newAttr2.UsageType = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkAttributeUsageType(0) # cost  
    newAttr2.DataType = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkAttributeDataType(2) # double  
    newAttr2.Units = esriGeoDatabase.esriNetworkAttributeUnits(9)  # meters  
    newAttr2.UseByDefault = True  

    # create network data set based on data element  
    fdxc = CType(fdsGDS, esriGeoDatabase.IFeatureDatasetExtensionContainer)  
    fdx = fdxc.FindExtension(esriGeoDatabase.esriDatasetType(19))  
    dsc = CType(fdx, esriGeoDatabase.IDatasetContainer2)  
    netds = CType(dsc.CreateDataset(nd), esriGeoDatabase.INetworkDataset)  

    # build network dataset now that it's created  
    netBuild = CType(netds, esriGeoDatabase.INetworkBuild)  
    for item in [edgeNet]:  
        netBuild.AddSource(item)  
    netBuild.AddAttribute(newAttr2)  
    netBuild.BuildNetwork(fsdGDS.Extent)  
    arcpy.CheckInExtension('Network')  
    return  

if __name__ == '__main__':  

    gdb = r'C:\mylocation\SanFrancisco.gdb'  
    create_nd(gdb)  
    print 'done'
```

And here's the error I am getting:

```
 netBuild.AddAttribute(newAttr2)
    COMError: (-2147212707, None, (u'The operation was attempted on an empty geometry.', u'"esri.Envelope"', u'esri_csGeoDatabase.hlp', 0, None))
```

Does anyone know why the error?

Comment: Hey, did you know that you can build a network dataset once manually, and then get its XML schema and then use this as the template for building new network datasets? Look at http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/network-analyst/create-network-dataset-from-template.htm. Building ND with arcobjects is painful if it's not your daily job :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am using ArcMap 10.3. I think it's only possible with Pro. Hmmm I guess I could upgrade to pro though I was trying to put that off as long as I can coz of all the python add ins I created.

Comment: *The operation was attempted on an empty geometry* - do you have data in all the feature classes?

Comment: I have data in the streets feature class. The 'sources' and 'sinks' don't exist. The person I got the code from used them and I just left the code in in case I decided to use them later. But I didn't add them to the network. I only added the streets 'for item in [edgeNet]:  
        netBuild.AddSource(item) '

Comment: The COM error says that there is no default junction evaluator http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/fdoError.htm (Ctrl + F 2147212707) perhaps evalNetAttr needs to be an IEvaluatedNetworkAttribute object instead of NewObj and the default evaluator populated http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002p9000000 before being cast to INetworkAttribute2

Comment: I have since abandoned this project as I figured I am way in over my head hehe. But thanks for your input. I will look into it when get a chance.