# What is purpose of arcpy.Array()?

Tags: arcpy, list, array

I am wondering what the purpose of `arcpy.Array()` is. It seems an intermediate step between creating a list of objects and performing some sort of conversion, for example, such as in the sample code for the [10.1 help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000006n000000).

```
    features.append(
            arcpy.Polyline(
                arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in feature])))
```

What purpose does the arcpy array serve? Why can't a list suffice? What's the logic behind this intermediate step?

Comment: It adds support for iteration via some of its methods. Seems similar to an iterator that can be created for lists with the built-in `iter()` function.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I believe that under the hood `arcpy.Array` is creating a Python object equivalent of the ArcObjects `IPointArray` interface, which is a required input for constructing line/polygon geometries. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000026w000000

Comment: +1. Agree. Very annoying. Used to be a list of lists

Comment: I think @crmackey is right. You can see this in the source of the `Array()` class in `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py` and the `ArrayMixin()` class in `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py` (replacing `10.1` with whatever version you have).

Comment: There's a lot of speculation here, but from what I think I understand, arcpy is a wrapper on the `arcgisscripting.pyd` (essentially a DLL) which I think is a course grained wrapper of a lot of ArcObjects functionality written in C++.  I do know for a fact that ArcObjects is not directly exposed in arcpy/arcgisscripting but you can get at them using the `comtypes` module.  My main point is I think that using `arcpy.Array` packages up a point collection in a C/C++ like object for easier translation into `arcgisscritping`, hence as @dmahr suggested may happen in `mixins.py`.

Comment: @crmackey I think you should create an answer from your comments here.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks for the suggestion.  I have turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all my own speculation, so take it with a grain of salt:

From what I think I understand, arcpy is a wrapper/bridge to the arcgisscripting.pyd (essentially a DLL) which I think is a course grained wrapper of a lot of ArcObjects functionality written in C++. [I do know for a fact that ArcObjects is not directly exposed in arcpy/arcgisscripting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python#comment64400_49091) but you can get at them using the comtypes module.

My main point is I think that using `arcpy.Array()` is the arcpy version of the ArcObjects [IPointArray](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IPointArray.htm) or probably more closely the [IPointCollection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IPointCollection.htm) interface. This data structure is probably enforced so that some internal data validation can happen under the hood to make sure there are valid inputs.  Just using lists of lists could cause some problems (explicit is better than implicit :) ) without validation.  That way, any `arcpy.Geometry` object knows it is getting valid input if it contains an `arcpy.Array` (even if it is empty).  The `arcpy.Array` also understands things like donut holes.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS provides its internal Functions through a python interface. Because some of them operate with a list of objects and they use the type Array as a function parameter, python lists do not work in this context. It isn't very 'pythonic' but there are examples in other modules too, numpy for example, where python standard types are substituted with specialized ones. The reason behind is, that there are tools like swig for 'converting' C++ Code to python, by putting a python caller to every c++ function (or class).
This is an interesting (at least old) alternative approach to access arcobjects from python:
[Accessing ArcObjects from Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python)

Answer (score -2):

One example for using an array would be creating a polyline from an array of points. I am by no means a python expert (yet) but from my understanding is that it can provide a way of automating creating features from a list (array) of other features.  Here is an article I found that may help a little.

[ESRI Desktop 10.1 Help Article](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000006n000000)

Comment: That is the exact same link OP posted.

Comment: I just realized that I posted a link to the same article/link you posted. Sorry!  LOL 

Did that help you any? I know you could get much more complicated tasks completed by using arrays.

Comment: @Paul, yes I realized that after I posted. I do believe though that this article answers the question. I do not think that it is an all inclusive article in regard to all the different scenarios in which to use it though.