# How to to get current legend column count using arcpy?

Tags: legend, arcpy

I can change the numbers of columns in the legend using arcpy.adjustColumnCount(column_count).

However, in my particular case I would like to know how many colums there are in the legend in the beginning and save that information as a variable, then change the number of columns to a specific value for a map and last change the number of colums back to the value of my variable.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear this python method exists.  You may however use ArcObjects [ILegendItem.Columns Property](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/Columns_Property/0012000007qp000000/) to access this information.

Comment: I always thought there would be a way that I once used. However, you might be right. Is there an easy way to implement an ArcObject method into a Python script w/o having any idea how ArcObjects works?

Comment: There are a number of Q/As on this site related to this topic, check out: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python