# Accessing graph properties in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages, graph

I am using data driven pages and arcpy.Graph() object to automate production of synchronised map/long-section series similar to this:

[image]

I'd like to keep vertical scale for long-section part. In order to do so I have to insert a couple of dummy points at the end of profile, because I cannot access these graph's properties via arcpy:

[image]

Does anyone know how to change min/max values for axis using script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, when generating a graph based on `addSeriesLineHorizontal` you don't get access to the min and max as you do with `addSeriesBarMinMax` for instance. `arcpy.Graph()` doesn't provide that fine-grained access to the graph properties.

You could either access [ArcObjects from Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python) to complement your workflow, or turn to a more powerful `matplotlib` that is delivered with standard ArcGIS for Desktop installation.

Comment: Perfect, matplotlib will do exactly what I want